# Using listings and subfigure together

Tags: listings, verbatim, subfloats, subcaption

I am writing a document in which code listings and diagrams appear side-by-side frequently. I am using the `listings` package for the code and `\includegraphics` for the diagrams. I want to put them both on the same figure.  I tried the `subfigure` package, but it does not allow verbatim environments inside the `\subfigure{}` argument.

The `fancyvrb` package has a workaround for this limitation: Using `SaveVerbatim` and `\BUseVerbatim`. However, I prefer to use only the `listing` package to get uniform styling for my code listings.

The `subfigure` manual includes some voodoo definition of a `subfloat` environment which can contain minipages with verbatim content. It is a clumsy solution. I also wonder why this solution was left out of the package itself.

Does anyone know a simple way to make these packages work together? Alt., is there a sub-figures package that is more verbatim-friendly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example using the subcaption package which is included in the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/caption.html) package bundle. (Note that the `\rule` command in my example is only a placeholder for `\includegraphics`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    for i:=maxint to 0 do
    begin
    { do nothing }
    end;
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{A listing}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{1.5cm}{1.5cm}
    \caption{A diagram}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{A listing and a diagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: The [subfigure](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/subfigure.html) entry of the TeX Catalogue OnLine states:

> This package is now obsolescent: new users should use [subfig or subcaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625/8547) instead.