# subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, subfloats, subcaption

On [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13558/how-to-put-two-images-next-to-each-other-with-a-and-b-labels), a comment by Martin H says: that one should forget about the `subfigure` and `subfig` packages and use `subcaption`. As `subfig` replaces `subfigure`, no argument there.

I am currently using `subfig` for displaying my subfigures and quite content with it. So I am wondering, what the advantages of using `subcaption` instead would be or if and **why** the use of `subcaption` is generally preferable to `subfig`.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`subfig` is not working properly with `hyperref`. The author of the caption package wrote [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=8710&start=0#p33579):

> Please note that the hyperref support within the subfig package is broken.
>   You could give my subcaption package a try instead.

Internet or Usenet search for subfig+hyperref would show compatibility and functionality issues, I guess we don't need to create an example for it here.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, really no need for an example here :)

Comment: meep.meep The problem now is `Do you think hyperref works properly`?   You write : If A does not work with B, but  A works with C then B is obsolete but if B works with D and C does not work  with D then what is your choice ?

Comment: @Altermundus: As this question is just about the choice between subfig and subcaption, I think your comment can make a new question. Besides that: subfig hasn't been changed since 2005. In contrast, hyperref got many updates and improvements, the most recent update has been just 7 days ago. And, in my experience, subcaption supports hyperref well.

Comment: Basically the intention of my comment was to point out that subfig is not actively developed anymore but subcaption is. Also, just a personal preference, the syntax of subcaption with \begin{} \end{} looks much cleaner un more readable to me

Comment: @Altermundus: I agree with Stefan and think this would need to be asked in a new question, and a very interesting one as off the top of my head I (and I guess we all) can think of several packages not working properly with `hyperref`. Just didn't know about this incompability yet.

Answer (score 129):

Pro subcaption:

- subfig's hyperref support contains bugs (which is clearly a problem of subfig and not of hyperref) while the subcaption package (hopefully ;-)) works fine with hyperref.
- The subcaption package offers enhanced hyperref support, `\subref*` will behave like `\ref*` (offered by the hyperref package), `\autoref` will work out-of-the-box, and the caption options `hypcap=` and `hypcapspace=` will work for sub-captions, too.
- The subfig package breaks the starred version of `\ContinuedFloat` offered by the caption package while the subcaption package does not.
- The subcaption package is more "in touch" with the caption package, supporting more common options like `list=on` etc., and offering similar commands to `\caption`, `\captionbox`, and the `figure` environment: `\subcaption`, `\subcaptionbox`, and the `subfigure` environment. (Please note that `\captionbox` is not avail yet but will be offered by the very next version 3.2 of the caption package.)
- Offers more ways to place and align sub-captions, e.g. `\subcaption` could be used to place a sub-caption (left or right) beside the figure.
- `\subcaptionbox` offers more optional arguments than `\subfloat`, e.g. for giving the box a specific width.
- Offers `\phantomsubcaption` for referencing without having a caption. (since version 1.1 of the subcaption package)
- Is supported by the bicaption package for typesetting bilingual sub-captions. (since version 1.1 of the subcaption package)

Pro subfig:

- The subcaption package needs the caption package while the usage of the caption package is optional in subfig. (The subfig package offers the option `caption=false`.) Because of that the subfig package could also be used with document classes which are incompatible to the caption package.
- The subcaption package does not offer top and bottom margins (yet) while the subfig package does. So when using the subcaption package one have to do the vertical spacing between sub-figures manually by using the `\vspace` command, `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, `\bigskip`, or similar.

Please note that I'm the author of the caption & subcaption package, so this list is far from being objective ;-)

But is the use of subcaption generally preferable to subfig? IMHO no, because the subfig package is a fine (and well documented) one, and if one is contented with the subfig package there is no need to switch.

Comment: Could you update the [Package maintainers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here/1182#1182) list on the meta site?

Comment: @Seamus Didn't know about that list before - just added my dog tag there.

Comment: Maybe it should be mentioned that the subfloats of `subfig` determine their width automatically, while `subfigure` from `subcaption` needs the width specified.

Comment: subfloats of `subcaption`, typeset with `\subcaptionbox`, will determine their width automatically, too.

Comment: `subfig` reserves space for caption even if you say `caption{}`. And if don't, you get warning from `hyperref`. `subcaption` does not have that problem.

Comment: You should add that `subcaption` is not compatible with RevTeX, as mentioned in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169803/1035) and [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228384/1035). This is a pretty serious bug to me, since I have no choice but to use RevTeX.

Comment: "Because of that the subfig package could also be used with document classes which are incompatible to the caption package." is already mentioned in the "Pro subfig" part.

Comment: Axel, is the bottom & top margins feature still unavailable? If something has changed, please update your answer.

Comment: @einpoklum No, unfortunately nothing has changed. I'm still hoping someone is writing a modern replacement for `float`, `floatrow`, `hvfloat`, and `subfig` resp. `subcaption` which would IMHO make much more sense than pimping `subcaption` which was only a small demonstration package for the sub-caption interface offered by `caption` in the 1st place.

Answer (score 1):

Just for documentation: In an up-to-date TeXlive 2011 installation, references to subfloats are off by one if the caption is above the subfloat (`position=top`). In the example below, this concerns references to subtables but not to subfigures.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup*[table]{position=top}
\captionsetup*[subtable]{position=top}
\captionsetup*[figure]{position=bottom}
\captionsetup*[subfigure]{position=bottom}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \subfloat[1]{11111\label{fig:1}} \subfloat[2]{22222\label{fig:2}}
    \caption{fig}\label{fig}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{table}
    \caption{tbl}\label{tbl}
    \subfloat[A]{aaaaa\label{tbl:a}} \subfloat[B]{bbbbb\label{tbl:b}}
  \end{table}

  Figure~\ref{fig} (\ref{fig:1}, \ref{fig:2})  and Table~\ref{tbl} (\ref{tbl:a}, \ref{tbl:b}).
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]

Switching to `subcaption` has resolved the issues, but I wish there would be a "compatibility" option so that code that used to work with `subfig` works also with `subcaption`. (Or at least a HOWTO with a reference to `\subcaptionbox`.)

Comment: @percusse: I don't see how Section 4.3 of the `subfig` manual (?) relates to referencing errors. The problem here is not the misaligned "a"-s and "b"-s, rather the references to the subtables (lowest line of text).

Comment: There were plans implementing an "compatibility" option, and very early versions of the `subcaption` package even offered `\subfloat` as well (but this was never a documented feature), but it has shown that this was not a very good idea. For example the `subfig` package allows having the `\label` in its contents while the `subcaption` package does not. Clearing this issue and removing more subtle differences would end up in writing more code for offering a compatible `\subfloat` than it took for the rest of the whole `subcaption` package. (Therefore I decided to drop that idea.)

Comment: Regarding the HOWTO: IMHO a HOWTO for migrating from `subfig` to `subcaption` offered by me would have been overbearing. But since `subfig` is "dead" more than 7 years now I may need reconsidering this...