# subfigure - how to eliminate (a), (b), ...

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I am using the `subfigure` package to reference parts of a figure. It works just fine when each of the subfigures is a single plot and I want LaTeX to insert labels (a), (b) ... under each. However, for consistency with other figures in my manuscript, I would like to have a single, multi-panel plot where I insert the (a), (b), ... manually (done using lattice in R). I can do this by still using

```
\subfigure[][]{%
  \label{beta}
  }%
```

for each subfigure and then inserting the single plot. However, this still gives the labels (a), (b), ... - now superimposed on each other. I would like to get rid of these, whilst still maintaining the functionality of subfigure which allows me to reference individual subfigures. I have tried `\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{}` but that removes the subfigure labels everywhere.

Would you know which command makes the subfigure labels under the plots and how to modify this to the desired effect?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is how I would do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Paris}}\quad
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Paris}}
  \caption{Caption about here}
  \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was what I needed - I have to admit I did not know about the `subfig` package.

Answer (score 9):

According to the help for the subfigure package, you can just drop the [] in the \subfigure command and it will not number the subfigure:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \vfill
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \vfill
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \vfill
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demofig}}
    \caption{All numbered but the last!}
    \label{fig:demofig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the result with MiKTeX 2.9:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: `subfigure` is succeeded by `subfig` so it should better not be used. An example : http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625/3235

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I am missing the point, but why do you need subfloat in the first place?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\columnwidth]{figures/fig1}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.4\columnwidth]{figures/fig2}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It seems that prettygully adds the subcaptions to the graphics in the R program.

Comment: I knew, I should not comment on stuff that I have no idea about...

Answer (score 3):

This works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
   %\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
   \centering
   \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Paris}}\quad
   \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Paris}}
   \caption{Caption about here}
   \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for this; so basically you are saying that the `captionsetup` is superfluous? Interesting.