# How to add combined cross-references for two subfigures?

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I want to have two subfigures, and then reference them like "as seen in Figure 2a,2b" -- so to combine them.

How can I do this? (or if you know a better way in lyx or latex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I slightly modified Gonzalo Medina's example in order to use the [cleveref](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package which (among other things) automatically determines the format of a cross-reference according to its "type".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{,}%% instead of " and\nobreakspace"
  \renewcommand{\crefmiddleconjunction}{,}% instead of ", "
  \renewcommand{\creflastconjunction}{,}% instead of " and\nobreakspace"
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{name1}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:one-one}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{name1}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:one-two}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:one}
\end{figure}

\dots\ as seen in \Cref{fig:one-one,fig:one-two} \dots

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Added redefinition of `\crefpairconjunction` & friends.

[image]

Comment: (+1) Good to know. Is there a way to customize `\Cref` (e.g., remove the "and", or join "a,b")? Because it seems this what the OP was looking for, unless I misunderstood the question and his comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want using the standard `\ref` command or `\ref` and `\subref` from the `subcaption` package (which should be preferred over the `subfig` package: [subcaption vs. subfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625/3954)). Here's a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{name1}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{name1}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

...as seen in Figures~\ref{fig:1a},\ref{fig:1b}...

...as seen in Figures~\ref{fig:1a},\ref{fig:1}\subref{fig:1b}...    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: I added a link to the question whose answer explains why subcaption should be preferred over subfig.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why `subcaption` is better than `subfig`?

Comment: @chi: I've just added the link to the relevant question and its answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [subfig](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/) package, and then `\label` each subfigure, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \subfloat[This is figA]{\label{fig:figA}\Large A}\hspace{3cm}
 \subfloat[This is figB]{\label{fig:figB}\Large B}
 \caption{Here goes the main caption}
 \label{fig:figAB}
\end{figure}

Here are Figure~\ref{fig:figA} and Figure~\ref{fig:figB}, and a combination thereof: 
Figure~\ref{fig:figA},\subref*{fig:figB}.
\end{document}
```

Replace `\Large A` and `\Large B` with your figures.

Here is the output:

[image]

I guess you can write a simple macro to wrap up the combined call to `\ref` and `\subref`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I do normally. However, imagine if I cite the labels consequetively, I will have something like this: (Figure 2A FIgure 2B) with fancy formatting. What I look for is to have (Figure 2a,b) or (Figure 2a,2b). Many thanks.

Comment: @Danial Can't you just use `\subref` instead of `\ref` for referencing part B? I'll add an example.