# Align captions of subfigures:

Tags: captions, subfloats

Hi I want to include the following two tikz figures in my document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[l]{.46\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{.8\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
from/.style={<-},
towards/.style={->},
protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
reaction/.style={}]
\node[protein] (p) at (-2,0) {$P$};
\node[protein] (ps) at (2,0) {$P^*$}
edge [towards, bend left] node[below=10pt,name=e2,minimum size =0mm] {$E_2$} (p)
edge [from,bend right] node[above=10pt,name=e1,minimum size = 0mm] {$E_1$} (p) ;
\draw[->] (e1) -- +(0pt,-12pt);
\draw[->] (e2) -- +(0pt,12pt);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\caption{Goldbeter-Koshland Loop.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[r]{.46\textwidth}
\resizebox{.8\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
from/.style={<-},
towards/.style={->},
protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
reaction/.style={}]
\node[protein] (p) at (-1.5,0) {$P$};
\node[protein] (ps) at (1.5,0) {$P^*$}
edge [towards, bend left] node[below=10pt,name=e2, minimum size =0mm] {$E_2$} (p)
edge [from,bend right] node[above=10pt,name=e1,minimum size =0mm] {$E_1$} (p) ;
\draw[->] (e1) -- +(0pt,-12pt);
\draw[->] (e2) -- +(0pt,12pt);
\node[protein] (q) at (0 , -3) {$Q$};
\node[protein] (qs) at (3 , -3) {$Q^*$}
edge [towards, bend left] node[below=10pt,name=e3, minimum size =0mm] {$E_3$} (q)
edge [from,bend right] node[above=10pt,name=e4,minimum size =0mm] {} (q) ;
\draw[->] (ps) -- +(0pt,-50pt);
\draw[->] (e3) -- +(0pt,12pt);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\caption{Goldbeter-Koshland Cascade.}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Everything is as I want it except that the caption in the two subfigures are not aligned.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: using `\begin{subfigure}[b]{.46\textwidth}` puts the captions at the bottom, but it also changes the justification of the figures- I assume that is not the desired output? there have been a few questions similar to this- I'll try and find the links

Comment: I think somebody edited the code I did not use the b option. Anyway this partially works, but the what I'd like more is to have the captions aligned at the bottom and the two tikzfigures aligned vertically..

Comment: Sorry Peter In the rush to post I forgot to include the \documentclass and the packages.

Comment: @LucaCerone my apologies, I edited the link with my 'partial' fix; you've confirmed what I thought you wanted though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can let the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package do the hard work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox
{%
\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth][1.5\FBheight]
  {\caption{Goldbeter-Koshland Loop.}}
  {\resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
from/.style={<-},
towards/.style={->},
protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
reaction/.style={}]
\node[protein] (p) at (-2,0) {$P$};
\node[protein] (ps) at (2,0) {$P^*$}
edge [towards, bend left] node[below=10pt,name=e2,minimum size =0mm] {$E_2$} (p)
edge [from,bend right] node[above=10pt,name=e1,minimum size = 0mm] {$E_1$} (p) ;
\draw[->] (e1) -- +(0pt,-12pt);
\draw[->] (e2) -- +(0pt,12pt);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\caption{Goldbeter-Koshland Cascade.}}
{\resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
from/.style={<-},
towards/.style={->},
protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
reaction/.style={}]
\node[protein] (p) at (-1.5,0) {$P$};
\node[protein] (ps) at (1.5,0) {$P^*$}
edge [towards, bend left] node[below=10pt,name=e2, minimum size =0mm] {$E_2$} (p)
edge [from,bend right] node[above=10pt,name=e1,minimum size =0mm] {$E_1$} (p) ;
\draw[->] (e1) -- +(0pt,-12pt);
\draw[->] (e2) -- +(0pt,12pt);
\node[protein] (q) at (0 , -3) {$Q$};
\node[protein] (qs) at (3 , -3) {$Q^*$}
edge [towards, bend left] node[below=10pt,name=e3, minimum size =0mm] {$E_3$} (q)
edge [from,bend right] node[above=10pt,name=e4,minimum size =0mm] {} (q) ;
\draw[->] (ps) -- +(0pt,-50pt);
\draw[->] (e3) -- +(0pt,12pt);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.46\textwidth}
```

and this gets us part of the way there, but not all the way- we still need to do some work!

We would ideally like to put in some `\vfill` commands that would put in the necessary white space around the smaller of the two `subfigures`. In order to do this successfully, we need to measure the size of the larger `subfigures` which can be done by storing it in a box.

So, the approach below does the following:

- stores the second (largest) picture in a `sbox` called `\tempbox`
- measures the height of the `\tempbox` and then applies the necessary amount of `\vfill` surrounding it to the first (smaller) `subfigure`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
% store the bigger of the two pictures in a vbox
\sbox{\tempbox}{%
    \resizebox{.368\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
    from/.style={<-},
    towards/.style={->},
    protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
    reaction/.style={}]
    \node[protein] (p) at (-1.5,0) {$P$};
    \node[protein] (ps) at (1.5,0) {$P^*$}
    edge [towards, bend left] node[below=10pt,name=e2, minimum size =0mm] {$E_2$} (p)
    edge [from,bend right] node[above=10pt,name=e1,minimum size =0mm] {$E_1$} (p) ;
    \draw[->] (e1) -- +(0pt,-12pt);
    \draw[->] (e2) -- +(0pt,12pt);
    \node[protein] (q) at (0 , -3) {$Q$};
    \node[protein] (qs) at (3 , -3) {$Q^*$}
    edge [towards, bend left] node[below=10pt,name=e3, minimum size =0mm] {$E_3$} (q)
    edge [from,bend right] node[above=10pt,name=e4,minimum size =0mm] {} (q) ;
    \draw[->] (ps) -- +(0pt,-50pt);
    \draw[->] (e3) -- +(0pt,12pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.46\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vbox to\ht\tempbox{
        \vfill
        \resizebox{.8\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            [bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
            from/.style={<-},
            towards/.style={->},
            protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
            reaction/.style={}]
            \node[protein] (p) at (-2,0) {$P$};
            \node[protein] (ps) at (2,0) {$P^*$}
            edge [towards, bend left] node[below=10pt,name=e2,minimum size =0mm] {$E_2$} (p)
            edge [from,bend right] node[above=10pt,name=e1,minimum size = 0mm] {$E_1$} (p) ;
            \draw[->] (e1) -- +(0pt,-12pt);
            \draw[->] (e2) -- +(0pt,12pt);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }
    \vfill
    }
    \caption{Goldbeter-Koshland Loop.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.46\textwidth}
    \usebox{\tempbox}
\caption{Goldbeter-Koshland Cascade.}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I borrowed the clever bit from [Vertical alignment with subfig and pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19554/vertical-alignment-with-subfig-and-pstricks)

Comment: Nice quick fix!