# tufte-latex and subfloat positioning

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats, tufte, subcaption

I'd like to have two rows of top-aligned images, with top-aligned captions below each.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29536/vertically-align-subfloats-at-the-top-while-having-subcaptions-vertically-aligne/29590#29590) provides a technique using the `floatrow` package, but something in that package (or one of its dependencies) doesn't play nice with the `tufte-latex` document classes. It breaks the caption positioning for all other floats (should be in the margin for the `tufte-handout` class).

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{A circle, bottom-aligned}
    \label{fig:circle}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{A second, smaller circle}
    \label{fig:circle}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{A third circle, with a long caption that will force more
      line breaks and mess up the pretty layout}
    \label{fig:circle3}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \\
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{another circle, in a new row}
    \label{fig:circle4}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{final circle}
    \label{fig:circle5}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Shapes with no corners. Ugly sub-figure layout. Caption for
    the figure is in the margin per the \texttt{tufte-handout}
    class}\label{fig:circles}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces: 
[image: output of MWE]

I'd like the tops of the figures to be aligned, and the tops of the captions in each row to be aligned.

Related: [Where'd my subfigure letters go?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85816/missing-sub-caption-numbers-with-tufte-latex)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an idea that borrows from my answer to

[Why is picture and matrix not drawn at the same height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83948/why-is-picture-and-matrix-not-drawn-at-the-same-height/)

and the links within.

[image: screenshot]

The idea is to measure the height of the biggest `subfigure`, and then use `\vfill` to `center` the other `subfigure` vertically.

Notice that I've changed the optional argument to `[t]` so that each `subfigure` is 'top aligned'.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}

% store the biggest picture
% store the bigger of the two pictures in a vbox
\sbox{\tempbox}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    % use the save box
    \usebox{\tempbox}
    \caption{A circle, bottom-aligned}
    \label{fig:circle}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    % for the other figures, you can use \vfill as follows
    \vbox to\ht\tempbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
            \vfill
    }
    \caption{A second, smaller circle}
    \label{fig:circle}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \usebox{\tempbox}
    \caption{A third circle, with a long caption that will force more
      line breaks and mess up the pretty layout}
    \label{fig:circle3}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \\
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{another circle, in a new row}
    \label{fig:circle4}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{final circle}
    \label{fig:circle5}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Shapes with no corners. Ugly sub-figure layout. Caption for
    the figure is in the margin per the \texttt{tufte-handout}
    class}\label{fig:circles}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```