# missing sub-caption numbers with tufte-latex

Tags: tufte, subcaption

Why are the numbers (acually, letters) for the sub-captions missing in the following MWE? note the colon that would follow the letter is printed.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{A circle, bottom-aligned}
    \label{fig:circle}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{A second, smaller circle}
    \label{fig:circle}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{A third circle, with a long caption that will force more
      line breaks and mess up the pretty layout}
    \label{fig:circle3}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \\
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{another circle, in a new row}
    \label{fig:circle4}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{final circle}
    \label{fig:circle5}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Shapes with no corners. Ugly sub-figure layout. Caption for
    the figure is in the margin per the \texttt{tufte-handout}
    class}\label{fig:circles}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I compiled your original code I got the errors

```
Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.


! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly
(caption)                in compatibility mode.
```

You can read more about this in [the documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/caption-eng.pdf), but essentially it means that the current `documentclass` (in your case `tufte-handout`) already has its own way of modifying the `caption` command.

You can get round this by using

```
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
```

as I have done in the following code- your images now have captions!

[image: screenshot]

I see that you've asked another question about the vertical alignment of the `subfigure`s, so we'll address that in that question :)

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{A circle, bottom-aligned}
    \label{fig:circle}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{A second, smaller circle}
    \label{fig:circle}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{A third circle, with a long caption that will force more
      line breaks and mess up the pretty layout}
    \label{fig:circle3}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \\
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{another circle, in a new row}
    \label{fig:circle4}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{final circle}
    \label{fig:circle5}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Shapes with no corners. Ugly sub-figure layout. Caption for
    the figure is in the margin per the \texttt{tufte-handout}
    class}\label{fig:circles}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 RTFL[.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85816/missing-sub-caption-numbers-with-tufte-latex)

Comment: When I try to \ref{fig:circles} I get a undefined reference. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini compile more than once :)

Comment: I did. :( Still no labels.

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini ah, now I understand why you asked [Are there any subfloat package that works with tufte-latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87410) I'm afraid I don't have an answer at the moment, but will look into it; the author of the `caption` and `subcaption` package is an active member of the site, maybe he'll be able to work some magic :)