# Problem with tufte-book and subfigure

Tags: subfloats, incompatibility, tufte

I'm having a problem using both the tufte-book class and the subfigure package. This problem started after a fresh install of texlive, and I can't find a reason for it.

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}


%opening
\title{Test.}
\author{Myself}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{adsf}
adsadfasdf
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 1.1\textwidth]{./path/to/figure}
    \caption{ \label{fig:ushaped} Ilustração da história da organização social dos humanos e primatas pré-humanos.}

\end{figure}

See figure \ref{fig:ushaped}.


\end{document}
```

If I set the class to `article` it works ok. If I set the class to `tufte-book` it gives the following errors:

```
! Argument of \@iiminipage has an extra }.
! Paragraph ended before \@iiminipage was complete.
```

I also notice that if I delete the `\label{fig:ushaped}` command, it works alright.

The problem is the same with the subfloats package.

I can't find the what's causing the problem. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: You have placed `\label{fig:ushaped}` inside `\caption` command. Try bringing that out. Also, `10pt` is not a valid option in `tufte`

Comment: Also, use width of your graphics to less than or equal to `\textwidth`

Comment: When I put the label out, the \ref command fails and only a ?? is displayed instead of the figure number

Comment: Try compiling twice `:)`

Comment: duplicate (?) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85816/missing-sub-caption-numbers-with-tufte-latex

Comment: Not exactly. My problem wasn't missing references, but no pdf being produce at all. And also, I wasn't using `subcaption` but `subfig`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `subfig` loads the `caption` package, which is incompatible with `tufte-book`. A solution is to load the `subfig` package (the successor to the obsolete `subfigure`) with the `[caption=false]` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


%opening
\title{Test.}
\author{Myself}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{adsf}
adsadfasdf
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{x}}\qquad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{y}}

\includegraphics[width = 0.9\textwidth]{./path/to/figure}
\caption{Ilustração da história da organização social dos humanos
             e primatas pré-humanos.\label{fig:ushaped}}
\end{figure}

See figure \ref{fig:ushaped}.


\end{document}
```

The `demo` option for `graphicx` is just to produce mock figures.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is this incompatibility new? The original file compiles perfectly in another computer were I didn't updated my linux distro.

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini I don't know, since I'm not a `tufte-book` user; but the error you get seems due to interaction between `tufte-book` and `caption`. Actually, it works if you move the `\label` command outside `\caption` (which is the way I prefer, anyway). However, I would be cautious in loading `caption` with `tufte-book`.