# Are there any subfloat package that works with tufte-latex?

Tags: captions, subfloats, tufte, subcaption

I'm trying a lot of subfloat-like packages with tufte-latex and all of them seem to interact badly with tufte-latex in the matter of labels, refs and captions. To captions I could find solutions thanks to you guys, but refs are still elusive.

Originally no numbering was appearing in the figures, but now the numbers appear but can't be referenced by the labels.

The following minimal examples show what's wrong. Both results in undefined references for the `tufte-handout` class and work perfectly with `article`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \subfloat[Subfigure 1] % caption for subfigure 1
  {
    \label{fig:sub1}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{subfig1.eps}
  }
  \subfloat[Subfigure 2] % caption for subfigure 2
  {
    \label{fig:sub2}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{subfig2.eps}
  }
  \caption{Results for subfigure}
  \label{fig:results}
  \end{figure}
  In the text, you can refer to subfigures of figure \ref{fig:results} as \ref{fig:sub1}, \ref{fig:sub2}, \subref{fig:sub1}, \subref{fig:sub2}.
\end{document}
```

This one also works ok with captions but mess up references (gives undefined references with tufte-handout, but works ok with article).

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{subfig1.eps}
    \caption{Subfigure 1}
    \label{fig:sub1}   
  \end{subfigure}
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{subfig2.eps}
    \caption{Subfigure 2}
    \label{fig:sub2}   
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Results for subfigure}
  \label{fig:results}
\end{figure}

In the text, you can refer to subfigures of figure \ref{fig:results} as \ref{fig:sub1}, \ref{fig:sub2}, \subref{fig:sub1}, \subref{fig:sub2}.
\end{document}
```

Are there any other subfloat packages that would work with tufte-latex? Or maybe a way to make the above packages work.

Comment: The code of `tufte-common.def` suggests it is compatible with the [`subfigure`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package. However, the`subfigure` package is often considered to be obsolete. I believe a feature request to the `tufte-latex` developers (=> compatibility with the `subcaption` package) seems reasonable...

Comment: "The subfigure and subfig packages redefine the caption and label
commands.  Unfortunately, the TL classes also need to redefine these
commands.  In the new version, I'm going go add some code to detect
the use of the subfigure/subfig package and try to work together with them."
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tufte-latex/subfig/tufte-latex/uSRjg7BftSU/UjnVeWsHNdQJ

Comment: IMHO "going to add some code to detect the use..." is the totally wrong approach. Contacting the author (=me) with the goal to implement a proper interface between `tufte` and `caption` would IMHO be a much better idea because AFAIK in the current situation neither the maintainer of `tufte` nor me (the maintainer of `caption`) is able to build a proper solution without relying on internals of the other class/package which could (of course) change in future versions...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as explained in the comments neither the cited `subfigure` package seem completely compatible. In the example this package allow correct references to the subcaptions, but hides the reference to the main caption.

However, luckily this can be solved if the main label is protected **and** included in the caption (not below the caption).

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfigure[\label{fig:sub1}Subfigure 1]
{ \includegraphics{subfig1.eps}}
\subfigure[\label{fig:sub2}Subfigure 2]
{ \includegraphics{subfig1.eps}}
\caption{\protect\label{fig:results}Results for subfigure}
\end{figure}

\noindent In the text, you can refer to subfigures of
figure \ref{fig:results} as \ref{fig:sub1}, \ref{fig:sub2},
\subref{fig:sub1}, \subref{fig:sub2}.

\end{document}
```