# Figures\Subfigures referencing in Latex

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I have a figure with 3 subfigures. I used the `\ref{fig:2}` in my text and I got 2a. Can anyone knows how to make it 2(a) instead of 2a?

Below is an example of my code:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph1.jpg}
    \caption{$y=x$}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph2.jpg}
    \caption{$y=sinx$}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph3.jpg}
    \caption{$y=cosx$}
    \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Three simple graphs}
\label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87595/change-format-of-reference-to-a-subfigure help?

Comment: Possibly `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}` and `\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple}` are sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

You can just do

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple}
```

Here's a complete example; notice that `\hfill` should go next to `\end{subfigure}` and that `sinx` should be `\sin x` (similarly for `\cos x`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,graphicx}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[sub]{
  labelformat=simple
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{$y=x$}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{$y=\sin x$}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{$y=\cos x$}
    \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Three simple graphs}
\label{fig:three-graphs}
\end{figure}

Here are the references: \ref{fig:1}, \ref{fig:2}, \ref{fig:3}
which are subfigures to figure~\ref{fig:three-graphs}.

\end{document}
```

See [Change format of reference to a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87595/change-format-of-reference-to-a-subfigure) for other customizations.

[image]