# 2x3 images spanning over a two column text

Tags: positioning, subfloats

I am trying to align 6 figures in a 2 by 3 organization over a two column text, but all my tries are in vain, the figures end up vertical. I've also tried minipages but no luck.

the tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{mdwmath}

\usepackage{mdwtab}

\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{epsfig}

%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering

\subfloat[A]{
\label{ex0}
\epsfig{figure=qa.eps,width=0.3\textwidth}
}                

\qquad

\subfloat[B]{
\label{ex1}
\epsfig{figure=qb.eps,width=0.3\textwidth}
}                

\qquad

\subfloat[C]{
\label{ex3}
\epsfig{figure=qc.eps,width=0.3\textwidth}
}                


\newline

%a row similar to the above

\end{figure*}
```

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not leave blank lines between the subfigures. You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\subfloat[A]{\label{ex0}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{qa}}\hfill
\subfloat[B]{\label{ex1}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{qb}}\hfill
\subfloat[C]{\label{ex3}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{qc}}\\
\subfloat[D]{\label{ex4}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{qd}}\hfill
\subfloat[E]{\label{ex5}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{qe}}\hfill
\subfloat[F]{\label{ex6}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{qf}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I used `\includegraphics` form the `graphicx` package instead of `\epsfig` from the obsolete `epsfig` package. Instead of forcing a `\quad` space between the figures, you can use `\hfill` which will distribute the spacing evenly.

I used the `demo` option for the `graphicx` package to make my example compilable for everyone. Do *not* use that option in your actual code.

If you don't mind using the `subcaption` package (this package behaves better than `subfig`, See [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625/3954)), you could use something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{qa}
  \caption{A}
  \label{ex0}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{qb}
  \caption{B}
  \label{ex1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{qc}
  \caption{C}
  \label{ex2}
\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{qd}
  \caption{D}
  \label{ex3}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{qe}
  \caption{E}
  \label{ex4}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{qf}
  \caption{F}
  \label{ex5}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you; didnt know that the blank lines between the subfigures that effective.