# How to move figure title to caption when using \subfig

Tags: captions, subfloats

This is my first time using \subfig because I have a figure (Figure 8) that contains two parts, and it was better to put them each on separate pages but one after the other, since they are related (hence, part a and part b) and each figure is as large as the page.

The captions for each part of the figure appear correctly under the figure, but the title "Figure 8" appears centered under the caption. Something like this

---

(a) Here is the caption of the

first part of the figure.

```
 Figure 8
```

---

I would like the caption to beggin as:  Figure 8(a): Here is the caption....
[or Figure 8.a: ]

How can I make the title of the figure to appear together with the caption?

Thank you very much in advance!

Here is the code I used:

```
\usepackage[caption=true]{caption,subfig}

....

\begin{figure}

\centering

\subfloat[Here is the caption of the first part of the figure (a)]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Figures/Profile_a.jpg}}

\caption{}

\label{fig:Prof_a}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}

\ContinuedFloat

\centering

\subfloat[Here is the caption of the second part of the figure (b)]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Figures/Profile_b.jpg}}

\caption{}

\label{fig:Prof_b}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: It seems to me that using the `subfloat` package would fit your needs better.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use the `subcaption` package instead of subfig: see [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625/3954). In the following example I (locally) redefined the `\thefigure` command to include the `subfigure` counter, and modified the format for the label of the subfigure caption so that the numbering and the captions will be produced by `figure` and not by `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty,aboveskip=-1em}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Figures/Profile_a.jpg}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Here is the caption of the first part of the figure (a)}
  \label{fig:Prof_a}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Figures/Profile_b.jpg}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Here is the caption of the second part of the figure (b)}
  \label{fig:Prof_b}
\end{figure}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I used the `demo` option for `graphicx` to make my example compilable for everyone; do *not* include the option in your actual code.