# How to put subcaptions below subtables, and increase gap between subtables with 'subfigure'?

Tags: spacing, positioning, captions, subfloats

Using 'subfigure', how can I create subtables within a table, such that a) subcaptions are underneath each subtable, and b) there's a reasonable horizontal gap between the subtables? So far I've only be able to get the subcaptions on top, and no reasonable gap, e.g. with following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\subtable[caption1]
{\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\subtable[caption2]
{\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{caption for whole table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One thing that doesn't work is '\usepackage[FIGBOTCAP]{subfigure}'. But having subcaptions underneath should be the default, according to the 'subfigure' manual.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I'd remove the explicit `\` (space) commands because the first column doesn't align properly (see also Percusse's output). Alternatively, add an explicit space after the `\hline` command.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of the `subfigure` package which is now obsolete and should be replaced with `subfig` package, you can use `subcaption` package with almost identical code. I am modifying the example in the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{A subtable}\label{tab:1a}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Another subtable}\label{tab:1b}
\end{subtable}
\caption{A table}\label{tab:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Nevermind the `figure` word. I just missed that.

Comment: Many thanks for this. It does the job beautifully; the only problem is that 'subcaption' is incompatible with 'subfigure' and messes up all the other things I've done with 'subfigure' :-( Any idea how to do the job using 'subfigure'?

Comment: @HarryMacpherson: `subfigure` is really obsolete.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that you should be using `subfigure` anyway. See [`subcaption` vs. `subfig`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig)for a flavor of these reasons. At least you should use `subfig` in my opinion...

Comment: OK thanks everyone. I've reached the conclusion, looking at what people say about `subfigure`, `subfig`, and `subcaption`, that I should ditch `subfigure`, load `subcaption`, RTFM for `subcaption` and work from there! Thanks for solving the problem I asked about, though! :)

Comment: I have a trouble with this solution and I have posted it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59414/issue-with-arranging-subtables