# Sub-labeling in tabular environment

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put subcaptions below subtables, and increase gap between subtables with 'subfigure'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40460/how-to-put-subcaptions-below-subtables-and-increase-gap-between-subtables-with)

I have two tables in the tabular environment with labels. I'd like to number the labels 1(a) and 1(b), like `subfigure` does.

How can I do this with tables?