# How to put a formula next to a table using the package subcaption

Tags: tables

I was working with a lot of little tables and I used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40460/how-to-put-subcaptions-below-subtables-and-increase-gap-between-subtables-with) link to include them on my script. Now I would like to put a formula related to the table next to each one. The formula has to be between a "cases" environment with three rows. Here is an example of two tables. There should be two "cases" environment, one next to each subtable, but I don't know how to include them. Thank you in advance.

```
\begin{table}[h!]

    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
        {\begin{tabular}{cc}
                \toprule
                \ $X$ & $Y$  \\
                \midrule
                12,5  & 0,11\\
                25    & 0,20\\
                50    & 0,37\\
                100   & 0,55\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}
        \caption{ $I=0,5\,A$}\label{tab:minisubtabladif_I=0,5}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
        {\begin{tabular}{cc}

            \toprule
                \ $X$ & $Y$  \\             
                \midrule
                12,5  & 0,18\\
                25    & 0,4\\
                50    & 0,73\\
                100   & 1,27\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}

        \caption{$I=1\,A$.}\label{tab:minisubtabladif_I=1}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What formula do you want to have? It's not very clear to me.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. For example, the first line of the "cases" would be m=(2,50\pm0,02)\,m, n=(4,5\pm 0,2)\,s the second and R=0,9998 the third.

Comment: But you want a cases environment next to each subtable? If you could post a small hand drawing, it would be easier to see exactly what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I want: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1RAGezNZL-RcTRCYVcyWTBiWG8

Comment: The link you posted has no free access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you wanted (more or less)?  The current version will not fit in 0.5\linewidth.  Also, I wasn't sure if you were using legal label names.

[image: stab in the dark]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for \toprule, etc.
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]

    \begin{subtable}{.75\linewidth}\centering
        {\begin{tabular}{cc}
                \toprule
                \ $X$ & $Y$  \\
                \midrule
                12,5  & 0,11\\
                25    & 0,20\\
                50    & 0,37\\
                100   & 0,55\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular} \(=\begin{cases}%
               m=(2,50\pm0,02)\,m\\
               n=(4,5\pm 0,2)\,s\\
               R=0,9998\end{cases}\)}
      \caption{ $I=0,5\,A$}\label{tab:minisubtabla1}
    \end{subtable}%

    \begin{subtable}{.75\linewidth}\centering
        {\begin{tabular}{cc}
            \toprule
                \ $X$ & $Y$  \\             
                \midrule
                12,5  & 0,18\\
                25    & 0,4\\
                50    & 0,73\\
                100   & 1,27\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular} \(=\begin{cases}%
               m=(2,50\pm0,02)\,m\\
               n=(4,5\pm 0,2)\,s\\
               R=0,9998\end{cases}\)}
       \caption{$I=1\,A$.}\label{tab:minisubtabla2}
       \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The environment cases must be on the right side of the table. The environment contains three lines, for example, the first one would be m=(2,50\pm0,02)\,m, n=(4,5\pm 0,2)\,s the second and R=0,9998 the third.