# Get combine a `sidewaystable` with a `subfloat` from `subfig`

Tags: tables, subfloats, rotating

I use the `subtables` environment from the `subfloat` package to combine table numbering (i.e., any tables I wrap in the `subtables` environment get labeled 1a, 1b, and so on). But I just learned on the [LaTeX wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats) how to use the `subfloat` environment from the `subfig` package for figures and it seems that I *should* use the `subfloat` environment from the `subfig` package for tables, too. Is this correct?

The rub is that I frequently use the `sidewaystable` environment from the `rotating` package. Can I rotate tables using the `subfloat` environment from the `subfig` package? (I can't figure out how from the [manual](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf).) This would allow side-by-side sideways tables. Or should I stick with my more naive approach using the `subfloat` package?

Here is an example of how I combine the `subtables` and `sidewaystable` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

Check out tables \ref{tab:first} and \ref{tab:second}.

\begin{subtables}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \hline
            a&b&c\\
            d&e&f\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{my first table}
        \label{tab:first}
    \end{sidewaystable}

    \begin{sidewaystable}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \hline
            a&b&c\\
            d&e&f\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{my second table, which is the same as the first}
        \label{tab:second}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{subtables}

\end{document}
```

Comment: did you _mean_ to have each subfloat on a separate page? -- i would expect to have the subfloat environments inside a single sidewaystable environment.

Comment: @anon -- Thanks. I didn't know that I could wrap multiple `tabular`s in one `sidewaystable`. Is there a good book on LaTeX? I learn most of this stuff in a vacuum, but the other programs I use (R, Stata) have consoles and `help` commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to obtain a `sidewaystable` look with multiple tables turned sideways without using `subfig` or even `rotating`. Here is a minimal example (which uses [`subfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfloat) for numbering):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfloat}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfloat
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\begin{document}

Check out Tables~\ref{tab:first} and~\ref{tab:second}.

\begin{subtables}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \rotatebox{90}{% Rotate table 90 degree CCW
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
        a&b&c\\
        d&e&f\\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{my first table}\label{tab:first}
    \end{minipage}
  } \qquad% <-------------- separation between sideways tables
  \rotatebox{90}{% Rotate table by 90 degree CCW
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
        a&b&c\\
        d&e&f\\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{my second table, which is the same as the first}\label{tab:second}
    \end{minipage}
  }
\end{table}
\end{subtables}

\end{document}
```

Rotation of the tables are obtained via [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\rotatebox{<angle>}{<stuff>}`. However, for tables (like `tabular` with a `\caption`), you need to box the contents you're rotating. I've done so using a `minipage` of width `0.5\linewidth`. This length is required, but you can also use the [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) which provides a similarly-named environment as an analogue to `minipage`, but shrinks (if needed) to the natural width of the box.

The space between "subtables" is given by `\qquad`, although a `\hspace{<len>}` would also work (where `<len>` is any recognized TeX length).

Finally, the `table` has been set as a float with specification `[ht]`, which is different from `sidewaystable`'s necessary `[p]` (page of floats) usage. However, you can modify this to suit.

For the moment, this does not incorporate [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating)'s on-the-fly +/90 degree rotating of floats which is page-dependent (which rotates the tables 90 degrees CCW for odd-numbered pages, and 90 degrees CW for even-numbered pages). However, it would be possible to implement such a feature using some additional packages like [`chngpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngpage), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer, which uses the `\sidewaystable` and `\subfloat` as requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{subcaption} %should be used instead of subfig
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

Check out tables \ref{tab:first} and \ref{tab:second}.

\begin{sidewaystable}[!h]
        \centering
        \caption{Example of subfloat and tables}\label{tab:main}
        \subfloat[][my first table\label{tab:first}]{
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \hline
            a&b&c\\
            d&e&f\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        }

        \vspace{2em}

        \subfloat[][my second table, which is the same as the first\label{tab:second}]{
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \hline
            a&b&c\\
            d&e&f\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Producing the following: referencing

[image]

... and tables on a new page (because of sidewaystable)

[image]

Note that, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure), you may want to use `subcaption` package instead of `subfig`.
(Just replace the package in the code above and the example works the same way)