# numbering several latex figures

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats

How is it possible to include figure labeling in latex? By labeling I mean that if I import several figures:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure1.pdf}
    \includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure2.pdf}
    \includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure3.pdf}
    \includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure4.pdf}
    \includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure5.pdf}
    \end{figure}
```

How can I number these figures, such as the first figure as (a) the second as (b) and so on... I would like these to show in the top left corner outside each graphic which I can then refer to in the caption.

Comment: Have a look at the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package.

Answer (score 7):

You need the `subfig` *or* the `subcaption` package for that. Here is an example using the `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[caption of the subfigure]{\includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure1.pdf}\label{fig:subfig-a}}\\
\subfloat[caption of the subfigure]{\includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure2.pdf}}\\
\subfloat[caption of the subfigure]{\includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure3.pdf}}\\
\subfloat[caption of the subfigure]{\includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure4.pdf}}...
\caption{caption of the whole figure}\label{fig:whole}
\end{figure}
The whole figure is~\label{fig:whole} and the first subfigure is~\label{fig:subfig-a}.
\end{document}
```

See [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig) for differences between the two packages

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put everything in a structure like this :

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure1.pdf}\\
    (a) Your label of choice\\
    \includegraphics[height = 0.2\textwidth,width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure2.pdf}\\
    (b) Your label of choice\\
 \end{tabular}
 \bigskip
 \caption{Your caption}
\end{figure}
```

This is what i did in one of my reports and the result is fine. the \bigskip is here to add some space between the last line of the tabular and the caption.

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. In this case, tables aren't it.

Comment: depends on the result you're looking for. my example works well for figure with width=\textwidth...

Comment: Semantically, `subfloat`s is a better choice. Functionally, I'd say `minipage`s and `subfloat`s are simpler, more flexible and more appropriate.