# compare two diagrams side by side

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption

I'm trying to compare two diagrams in pdf format side by side. 
I have this post - [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side) to get some hint.

This is the code that I'm coming up with.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{before.pdf}
\caption{(a) Before}
\end{minipage}%

\hfill\vrule\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{after.pdf}
\caption{(b) After}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{Hello}
\end{figure}
```

And this is the result, which is not exactly what I expected.

[image]

- What modifications are needed to make the pictures sit side by side?
- I just want the caption (a) Before and (b) After without any `Figure` prepended. What should I do?

Comment: Avoid the empty line before `\hfill\vrule\hfill`; also declare `\centering` after `\begin{figure}`

Comment: And maybe use `width=\linewidth` instead of `scale=0.30` in your `\includegraphics`since otherwise the width of the image may exceed the width of the minipage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can solve perfectly the problem with `minipages`, for sub-figures with captions enumerated with letters (a,b,..) you can use also the package `subcaption` to simplify a little your code, as you do not need write "(a)" and "(b)", but mainly because the flexibility that you have with this package, as listing the subfigures. Note that neither is it necessary in the MWE the use of `\centering` nor include file extension (.pdf).

Note: Remove the `demo` option in `graphicx` package to use your diagrams instead of the black boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove option for real images
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures    
\vspace{3cm}

\begin{figure}[h]%

\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{before}
\caption{Before}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill\vrule\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{after}
\caption{After}
\end{subfigure}%

\caption[Hello]{Hello, this a minimal working example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use also `subfig` or `subfigure` packages for the same reasons. See  [Setting default distance between subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68025/setting-default-distance-between-subfigures) for examples with these packages.

Comment: Compilation of your LaTeX example on my mac gives me this error message: `ERROR: Package subcaption Error: 'caption' package not loaded`

Comment: @prosseek, have you `caption.sty` in your mac? Try with `\usepackage{caption}` before of `\usepackage{subcaption}`. At least in TeXLive2012 this is not needed, as `subcaption` load also `caption.sty` and `caption3.sty`, but who know ...

Comment: \usepackage{caption} solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to egreg and Vincent, I could make the correction.
The problem was the empty line that caused the wrong alignment, and I replaced `caption` with `centering` to remove the `Figure`

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{before.pdf}

(a) Before
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\vrule\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{after.pdf}

(b) After
\end{minipage}
\caption{Hello}
\end{figure}
```

---

Comment: One `\centering` for `minipage` is sufficient: it is not a command taking arguments, but a declaration.