# Obtaining the behavior of both subfigure and subcaptionbox in the subcaption package

Tags: subfloats

In the `subcaption` package, the default way to create subfigures is when the `subfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  Subfigure1 is located here
  \caption{Subfigure1 caption}
  \label{subfig:1}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  Subfigure2 is located here
  \caption{Subfigure2 caption}
  \label{subfig:2}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{Figure caption}
 \label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I like this syntax, especially in that the figure comes first, then the caption, then the label for the caption. However, I don't like having to specify the `\textwidth` within the environment.  I would prefer that this parameter be optional with the default value being the width of the figure.

One solution to fix this problem is to use a savebox, but then source for the figure is (slightly) divorced from its primary location of use.

The `subcaption` package provides a solution for this problem via the `\subcaptionbox` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \subcaptionbox{Subfigure1 caption\label{subfig:1}}{
  \centering
  Subfigure1 is located here}
 \subcaptionbox{Subfigure2 caption\label{subfig:2}}{
  \centering
  Subfigure2 is located here}
 \caption{Figure caption}
 \label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now specifying `\textwidth` is optional and defaults to the width of the figure, but the source is much less readable.  I dislike this solution for several reasons:

1. It is easier to write, read, and understand large amounts of code placed within `\begin{}...\end{}` then within `\someCommand{...}`.  (It is so easy to use the wrong number of curly braces.)
2. The figure, caption, and label out written out of order from the way they are typeset (by default), which is the order in which I think about them.
3. The location to place the caption is not explicit.  (It is just a required value to the `\subcaptionbox` placed between some `{}`'s, so a fellow coauthor that doesn't know this syntax won't know how to add a caption if it is currently blank.)

### Question:

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?  How can I get behavior equivalent to using the `subfigure` environment but with the specification of `\textwidth` being optional (and defaulting to the width of the figure)?

(This question is about the `subcaption` package because it seems that this is [the best package for subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure/13778#13778).  I am open to suggestions that another package is better and fulfills my requirements.)

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't support all the features of `\subcaptionbox`: the optional argument `<inner-pos>` can't be expressed.

The optional argument to the `xsubcaption` environment is the explicit width of the subfigure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\environfinalcode{}
\NewEnviron{xsubcaption}[1][-1sp]
 {\let\xsc@theoptcaption\@empty
  \let\xsc@thecaption\@empty
  \let\xsc@thelabel\@empty
  \expandafter\xsc@checkcaption\BODY\caption\xsc@checkcaption
  \expandafter\xsc@checklabel\BODY\label\xsc@checklabel
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\subcaptionbox
      \ifx\xsc@theoptcaption\@empty\else
        [\unexpanded\expandafter{\xsc@theoptcaption}]%
      \fi
      {\unexpanded\expandafter{\xsc@thecaption}%
       \ifx\xsc@thelabel\@empty\else
         \noexpand\label{\unexpanded\expandafter{\xsc@thelabel}}%
       \fi} 
      \ifdim#1=-1sp % no optional argument
      \else
        [#1]%
      \fi
      {\unexpanded{\renewcommand\caption[2][]{}\renewcommand{\label}[1]{}}%
       \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}}\x
}

\long\def\xsc@checkcaption#1\caption#2\xsc@checkcaption{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\expandafter\xsc@getcaption\BODY\xsc@getcaption}%
}
\long\def\xsc@getcaption#1\caption#2#3\xsc@getcaption{%
  \if[\detokenize{#2}%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\expandafter\xsc@getcaptionopt\BODY\xsc@getcaptionopt}%
  {\def\xsc@thecaption{#2}}%
}
\long\def\xsc@getcaptionopt#1\caption[#2]#3#4\xsc@getcaptionopt{%
  \def\xsc@theoptcaption{#2}%
  \def\xsc@thecaption{#3}%
}
\long\def\xsc@checklabel#1\label#2\xsc@checklabel{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\expandafter\xsc@getlabel\BODY\xsc@getlabel}%
}
\long\def\xsc@getlabel#1\label#2#3\xsc@getlabel{%
  \def\xsc@thelabel{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{xsubcaption}
\centering
Subfigure1 is located here
\caption{Subfigure1 caption}\label{subfig:1}
\end{xsubcaption}
\begin{xsubcaption}
\centering
Subfigure2 is located here
\end{xsubcaption}
\begin{xsubcaption}[3cm]
\centering
Subfigure3 is located here
\caption[A]{BBB}
\end{xsubcaption}
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\ref{subfig:1} \ref{fig}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use the `environ` package to collect the environment's body in the macro `\BODY`. Then I check whether `\caption` appears in the body; if so I check whether it has an optional argument. In caption (and the "list caption", if present) is stored in a macro and then the whole `\subcaptionbox` instruction is built from the various parts (when the body is typeset, `\caption` is redefined to do nothing).

***(Added)*** The same checks are performed to catch a `\label` command outside the argument of `\caption` (both ways are supported, of course).

Finally the `\subcaptionbox` macro with all arguments determined with the code above is executed. It appears to be complicated, but it's not really difficult: it's a standard way to catch the presence of some token (`\caption` and `\label`) in a list of tokens, in this case the contents of the environment, which is available as the expansion of `\BODY`.

Comment: I want the subfigure label to appear after the subfigure caption but also don't want you to "introduce more checks".  The code you have in the preamble is already completely unreadable.

Comment: @TysonWilliams "I want" seems quite unpolite. The code is complex looking, because one has to look for a possibly missing `\caption`. It's no big deal to cope also with `\label` outside the argument of `\caption`.

Comment: What should I say instead of "want"?

Comment: "I would like", for example. :) However, the present version allows for `\label` to be outside the argument of `\caption`.

Comment: Re: your addition.  This code may be understandable to you, but it is completely opaque to me.  Now, I certainly admit that I don't know as much LaTeX as I would like (though TEX.SE has taught me an incredible amount).  However, the solution "I would like" needs to be understandable to my coauthors as well.  If you put this functionality into a package, wrote documentation for it, and got it into TeX Live, then this answer would be acceptable.

Comment: @TysonWilliams A difficult task usually requires a complex solution, I don't think there are "elementary" ways of doing it. You can propose the addition to the author of `subcaption`. Do you know how the ABS braking system works? Do you need to know for using it? :)

Comment: "A difficult task usually requires a complex solution, I don't think there are 'elementary' ways of doing it." I don't doubt this, but I want the "complicated solution" hidden from any of my source via abstraction. Surely you can appreciate this. As for the ABS, they have successfully abstracted the details to the point that everyone knows how to use it AND not have to concern themselves with any of the implementation details.

Comment: @egreg, I'm trying to use your macro in a document of mine, and am getting `! You can't use \`\hrule' here except with leaders. \caption@hrule ->\hrule                         \@height \z@ l.341   \end{xsubcaption}` - should I file another question?

Comment: @einpoklum I guess so: there must be some different setting to cope with.

Comment: @TysonWilliams you can hide the "complicated solution" in a separate file and load it with an '\input'. A few comments (lines starting with a percent sign) at the beginning of the file could tell everyone what it does, how to use it and where it comes from.