# caption placement above and below: subcaption vs. floatrow

Tags: floats, captions

I have a pretty long document with lots of figures. So far, I have had all captions on top, for both tables and figures, and that's how they are placed in the code.

Now, I want to change the figure captions to be below the corresponding figures without having to change each individual figure in the code, while leaving tables the way they are. I have read that the `floatrow` package can do this, and so I started looking into it. For regular figures, this works fine, but I'm also using subfigures generated with the `subcaption` command, and there, `floatrow` doesn't seem to have an effect.

Is it possible to have `floatrow` also affect the placement of captions (above or below) generated with the `subcaption` package - or is there some other, more lightweight package that can take care of this? Floatrow is a really extensive package, and I'm really only interested in changing the top vs. bottom issue of the caption placement.

Comment: If you use `\subcaptionbox` (offered by the `subcaption` package as well) the position of the caption can be simply altered by package option.

Comment: That was an excellent hint. With the help of egregs answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81953/obtaining-the-behavior-of-both-subfigure-and-subcaptionbox-in-the-subcaption-pac I was able to come to a very satisfying resolution!