# Presenting multiple figures in a proper and readable way under a same caption

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

I have 6 figures and I wanted to plot them in a proper way in a single page. It is important to remain readability. Moreover, including the sub-caption and sub-label is important. Possibly including a border for set of figures is better.

Any suggestions:

Figures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are several packages for sub-figures, namely: `subcaption` and `subfig`. With such packages you can create a single figure, and inside the `figure` environment you can have sub figures (see the documentation of the single package for the syntax) each with its own caption.

Here is a possible way to arrange your figures (I have use `\rule` to exemplify the structure, please replace it  with the appropriate code for including your graphics)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
      \centering
      \rule{3cm}{2cm}
      \caption{First}\label{sf:first}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
      \centering
      \rule{3cm}{2cm}
      \caption{Second}\label{sf:second}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
      \centering
      \rule{3cm}{2cm}
      \caption{Third}\label{sf:third}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
      \centering
      \rule{3cm}{2cm}
      \caption{Fourth}\label{sf:fourth}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
      \centering
      \rule{3cm}{2cm}
      \caption{Fifth}\label{sf:fifth}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
      \centering
      \rule{3cm}{2cm}
      \caption{Sixt}\label{sf:sixt}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Global Caption}\label{fig:all}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image]

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete now and should be avoided. It has been superseded by `subfig`. See this question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference although it may be a little complex for this question, would be to use ggplot2 from R, using a grid to arrange the 6 plots. Then by using knitr, these can be written on the fly from within latex, embedded in a single figure environment.

I am sure someone can come up with a simpler example in tikz.

Have a look at knitr http://yihui.name/knitr/
Have a look at ggplot2 http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/