# Subfigure link in List Of Figures don't redirect to the subfigure

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, subfloats

I'm having some problems with my List Of Figures.

I have a couple subfigures in my report, and when I go to the list of Figures, the link for the main caption works well and redirects to the right page.

But when I click on the link on one of the captions of the subfigures, I get redirected to the 1st page of my report.

Is there a way to make the link from the subfigure's caption redirect to the subfigure itself ?

Here's my code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=NavyBlue,citecolor=Fuchsia,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\Chapter{Coucou toi}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[\textwidth]{Fig1.jpg}
\label{fig:Figure1}}
\qquad
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Fig2.jpg}
\label{fig:Figure2}}
\caption[Blabla]{Bloblo\protect\footnotemark}
 \label{fig:Figure}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Source : \itshape{\url{http://www.coucou.com}}}
\noindent
\end{document}
```

Don't know if it helps, but when I compile I get the error : `name{subfigure.3.3}` has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) `subfig` not working with `hyperref` is a known issue- have a look at [subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure)

Comment: Thanks!
And how would the application of the subcaption package would look like on the code below ? 
Is it compatible with the options already loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`subfig`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subfig) has some known issues about working with the [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) package, as described in [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure)

Here's a version of your code that uses the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package which provides the `subfigure` environment. The hyperlinks work as expected. Just note that you should remove the `demo` option from the `graphicx` package when you're ready for your 'live' document.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
                        linkcolor=blue,
                        urlcolor=blue,
                        citecolor=purple,
                        linktocpage]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{My chapter}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig1}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:Figure1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig2}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:Figure2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[Blabla]{Bloblo\protect\footnotemark}
    \label{fig:Figure}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{Source : \itshape{\url{http://www.coucou.com}}}

\end{document}
```