# insert text RIGHT under image ABOVE caption

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

How do I place text RIGHT below an image (above the caption) within `subfig`? Here Is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig} 

\begin{document}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=bf,textfont=normalfont,singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright}
\captionsetup[figure]{singlelinecheck=off}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[\textit{\textit{D. pulex}}
\newline \tiny \url{commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Daphnia_pulex.png}
\newline \tiny Photos by Paul Hebert]{\label{dpulex}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{dpulex.png}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is what it prints:

[image]

So I'd like those two lines written in `tiny` to appear below the image and above "(a) D. pulex". Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just include it below the image, rather than above the caption:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=bf,textfont=normalfont,singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright}
\captionsetup[figure]{singlelinecheck=off}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[\textit{D.\ pulex}\label{dpulex}]{%
    \centering\parbox{0.48\linewidth}{%
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
      {\tiny \url{commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Daphnia_pulex.png} \\
      Photos by Paul Hebert}%
    }
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The skip between the URL and credits can be changed to suit your needs. For example, use `\\[-.5\baselineskip]` instead of `\\`, say):

[image]

I've used a `\parbox` purely to have a left-aligned block. However, you can modify this to your liking. The fundamental idea remains the same.

Also, [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) should actually be loaded last in this instance. See [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)

Comment: This would be great if only the space between lines wasn't so great. Is there any way i can resolve this (with or without the parbox)

Comment: @FarZin: Just use `\\[-.5\baselineskip]` instead of the regular ``\\`` I have.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use the `subcaption` package instead of the `subfigure` package (which, I believe, is deprecated), you could use something like the following method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit [demo] in real version
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=bf, 
   singlelinecheck=off,
   justification=raggedright}
\captionsetup[figure]{singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dpulex.png}

\tiny Photos by Paul Hebert

\url{commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Daphnia_pulex.png}

\caption{\textit{D. pulex}}\label{dpulex}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the reference to `subfigure`? The OP uses `subfig`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - I've read in quite a few places that the `subfig` package is deprecated. I've actually never used that package in my own papers, and use only `subcaption`.

Comment: it hasn't had updates lately, but please read [`this comment`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13778/3954) by Axel Sommerfeldt saying that it is perfectly usable. The obsolete package is `subfigure`, not `subfig`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - Thanks for this, I appreciate it.