# Subcaption not in the centre in subfigure package

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

In LaTeX, everything works fine with `subfigure` package, only one trouble is coming;
The subcaptions are placed a little towards left from the centre of two figures side by side, which doesnt loook good,,, I have tried everything using `nooneline`, `hang` , `centrelast` etc. but no desired result is coming . Kindly suggest me how could i move either the captions towards centre of figures or the figures such that subcaptions comes in centre.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work just fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{demo}
            \caption{Skeletal}
        \label{fig:SkeletalTissue}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{demo}
            \caption{Cardiac}
        \label{fig:CardiacTissue}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Types of Muscular Tissue}
    \label{fig:MuscularTissue}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the result.  Is this what you were looking for?[image]

Comment: I copied ur script and added my figure file in it. But i still got the same result. I have added link of the result i have recieved.....                                                                     http://tinypic.com/r/2v1wvo1/5

Comment: Dear @user2467143, your captions are centered, but are centered to the whole figure.  This means the part of the axis where "amplitude m/s^2" is written is also part of the graphic.  For tweaking your captions you can add `\hspace*{5mm}\caption{Your caption}`.  5mm have been selected arbitrary, but you can choose as much space as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with my master thesis and think I found a solution! The problem is that you have too much white "waste" around the figure. You can adjust the position of the image by for instance using \hline{-10pt}.

You need to use packages `graphicx`, `float`, and `subcaption`

Here is one example where four subfigures are located in 2x2, and the v-space is for obtaining some vertical "air" between the figures:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
                \hspace{-10pt}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure1}
                \subcaption{A loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text over several lines!!} \vspace{1cm}} %\vspace is for obtaining some vertical "air" between the figures. 
        \end{subfigure}
        \qquad %for horizontal spacing
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
            \hspace{-10pt}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure2}
        \subcaption{A loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text over several lines!!}
    \end{subfigure}
\\ %for changing line to next 2 figures    
              \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
          \hspace{-10pt}
              \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure3}
               \subcaption{A loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text over several lines!!}
        \end{subfigure}
        \qquad %for horizontal spacing
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
            \hspace{-10pt}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure4}
        \\subcaption{A loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text over several lines!!}
        \end{subfigure} 
\caption{The total caption which is not affected.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure subfigure package is really archaic and problematic so it is already a solution just using `subcaption` but adjusting manual spacing is not the way to go. The package offers various customization possibilities.

Comment: @percusse - The user is not using the `subfigure` package. I agree with you, though, that all these manual spacing adjustments aren't the way to go.

Comment: @Mico Right. My wording is not that good. I meant that `subcaption` is much more than replacing `subfigure` but apparently failed to reflect that. .