# Problem with hyperref and subfloats

Tags: hyperref, subfloats

I'm using `subfloats` rather extensively, and want to use `hyperref` to refer to the `subfloats`.

It works, sort-of. In the below example, when clicking the hyperref to the first figure, the `pdf` goes nicely to the top-left of the figure. However, when clicking the reference to the second figure, the `pdf` goes to near the bottom of the second figure, such that most of the figure is out of view.

[image: screenshot]

`Hyperref` goes to the light green crosses, which is fine for `1.1a)`, but I want it to go to the blue cross for `1.1b)

Below is my MWE, which I build by running `pdflatex` twice using `texlive 2012`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

This will be a reference to the first part of Figure~\ref{fig:firstfigure}

This will be a reference to the second part of Figure~\ref{fig:secondfigure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \subfloat[Some subfloat caption for the first figure goes here.]{\label{fig:firstfigure}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{./placeholder}}\hspace{0.15\textwidth}              
    \subfloat[And some other caption for the second subfigure goes here.]{\label{fig:secondfigure}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{./placeholder}}
\caption{\protect\subref{fig:firstfigure} is the first figure. \protect\subref{fig:secondfigure} is the second figure.}\label{fig:somefigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any insight in how to fix the `hyperref` behaviour for the second `subfigure` is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The `hyperref` support of the `subfig` package is buggy, this is a known problem. See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure

Comment: Thanks! I was already messing around in the direction of `subcaption`, and I think I got it working properly. I'll post the MWE of the solution I found in a moment.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help! I see you've ditched the \protect before the \subref commands. Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: @IceRabbit See my comment to your answer which you just have deleted. BTW: I have deleted my answer after seeing that you have just answered, too. :-D I would suggest that you undelete your answer!? At least we should keep one of our answers :-D

Comment: We're both too modest. ^_^ I'll undelete my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find the solution by ditching the `subfig` package in favour of the `subcaption` package, as also suggested by Axel Sommerfeldt.

The MWE of my solution is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

This will be a reference to the first part of Figure~\ref{fig:firstfigure}

This will be a reference to the second part of Figure~\ref{fig:secondfigure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \subcaptionbox{Some subfloat caption for the first figure goes here.\label{fig:firstfigure}}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{./placeholder}}\hspace{0.15\textwidth}
    \subcaptionbox{And some other caption for the second subfigure goes here.\label{fig:secondfigure}}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{./placeholder}}
\caption{\protect\subref{fig:firstfigure} is the first figure. \protect\subref{fig:secondfigure} is the second figure.}
\label{fig:somefigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: The `\protect` isn't needed in front of `\subref` when using the `subcaption` package, it should work fine without, too. (But this extra `\protect` does not make any harm, it's just superfluous.)