# Using subfloat with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, subfloats

I have several large figures which I have split over several pages using the `\subfloat` command. I would like each page in the figure to display the Figure number, but the full caption should only be displayed on the last page. Only the full caption should appear in the list of figures. The following code shows a minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htpb]
    \centering
        \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\
        \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\
        \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \ContinuedFloat
    \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\
        \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\
        \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \ContinuedFloat
        \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\
\caption{}
\label{fig:intensitystructureplots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, with the `hyperref` package included the figure numbering for the figure containing subfloats goes: Figure 2 for the first figure of the group (correct), then Figure 1, then Figure 0. All three floats also have an entry in the list of tables. Turning off `hyperref` solves the problem of decrementing numbers, all are now labelled Figure 2, however the three Figures linked by the `\ContinuedFloat` command all have an entry in the List of Figures table, when only the last should be listed as they are all part of the same figure. Using the `\phantomcaption` command removes the entry from the List of Figures, but also removes the label from the Figure.

Comment: Why are you using 3 `\caption`s for the same `figure`? This is the source of the problem. If you remove `\ContinuedFloat` in fact the problem goes away.

Comment: The reason is that these figures are split over several pages; hence I think the individual pages should show the Figure number, otherwise it just appears as page with a picture on and the reader has no idea which figure it is or why there isn't a caption.

Comment: Yes, but why are you using both `\caption` and `\ContinuedFloat` in the same figure? The latter is to be used for the same figure.

Comment: If I remove \caption, then the pages have no Figure number. If I remove \ContinuedFloat the Figure number increments.

Comment: Just to solve your problem with `hyperref` load `subfig` with the option `caption=false`, i.e. `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`. But I don't know how to remove multiple entries in LOF.

Comment: @karlkoeller  With `caption=false` the numbering seems to be correct (again), but one get warnings like `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.0.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`, furthermore the hyperlinks in the LOF are not jumping to the right figure.

Comment: I saw your questions: all not accepted. Are you sure that no answer to your question does solve your questions? Please accept an question, if an answer worked for you personally. See[What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the `hyperref` support within `subfig` is broken. See also:

[subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure)

[Problem with hyperref and subfloats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119974/problem-with-hyperref-and-subfloats)

...

The only solution I'm aware of is switching to the/my `subcaption` package [1]:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany]{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htpb]
    \centering
        \subcaptionbox{}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\
        \subcaptionbox{}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\
        \caption[]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \ContinuedFloat
    \subcaptionbox{}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\
        \subcaptionbox{}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\
        \caption[]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \ContinuedFloat
        \subcaptionbox{}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{}
        }\\caption{}
\label{fig:intensitystructureplots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(LOF entries could be suppressed by using `\caption[]{...}`.)

[1] Sorry for the shameless self-advertising, but the broken `hyperref` support in `subfig` was one of the main reasons why I have written `subcaption`.

Comment: It has been 7 years. Is this still the case?