# Labeling and referencing subfigures

Tags: floatrow

I am trying to use the floatrow package to place to figures side by side in a `subfloatrow`, while this works fine I have problems following the sugested labeling method from the manual.

On page 73, of the 2009/08/02 version of the english manual of `floatrow` it reads:

> The label command \Flabel can be defined like following:
>   preamble>
>   \newseparatedlabel\Flabel{figure}{subfigure}
>   preamble>
>
> or, for all floats:
>
> preamble>
>   \makeatletter
>   \newseparatedlabel\Flabel{\@captype}{sub\@captype}
>   \makeatother
>   preamble>

However, if I try to define the `\Flabel` command like that I get an errormessage saying that `\newseparatedlabel` is undefined.

**What is the correct way to label figures in `subfloatrows`?**

---

MNWE(minimal NON working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}                           %subfigures
\makeatletter
\newseparatedlabel\Flabel{\@captype}{sub\@captype}
\makeatother   
\begin{document}
    \ldots    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know `floatrow` package at all. For subfigures I use `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[Foo]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{foo}\label{fig:foo}}\hfil
  \subfloat[Bar]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{bar}\label{fig:bar}}
  \caption{Figures of Foo and Bar}\label{fig}
\end{figure}
Here in fig. \ref{fig} we can see Foo in fig. \ref{fig:foo} and Bar in fig. \ref{fig:bar}.
\end{document}
```

Here in fig. 1 we can see Foo in fig. 1a and Bar in fig. 1b.

If you want to have "Foo in fig. 1 and Bar in fig. 2" you can use minipage cheat:

```
\begin{figure}
 \begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}
  \caption{Foo}\label{fig:foo}
 \end{minipage}\hfil
 \begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bar}
  \caption{Bar}\label{fig:bar}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Edit:
Using `floatrow` you can achieve same result with this code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{floatrow}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[H]
 \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
 {\begin{subfloatrow}
   \sidesubfloat[Foo]{\includegraphics{foo}\label{fig:foo}}%
   \sidesubfloat[Bar]{\includegraphics{bar}\label{fig:bar}}%
   \end{subfloatrow}}
 {\caption{CCC}\label{fig}}
 \end{figure}

 See \ref{fig:foo}.

 \end{document}
```

For more options see chapter 7.1 in [floatrow manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf).

Comment: +1 for effort, however I am still looking for the solution with the `floatrow` package, since it seemed to have more configuration options than `subfig` when I looked arround and decided which package I want to learn for `subfigures`.

Comment: @ted A good read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure

Comment: @percusse I am not quite seeing the point. While I take from that read that I would use `subcaption` over `subfig`since I use `hyperref`, I care about `floatrow`. It seemed to offer some more formating options (sideway captions, frames,...) and I liked the styles system which reminds me of TikZ. If you are trying to suggest for me to use another package, could you please name the advantages/disadvantages? Or am I missing your pont?

Comment: @ted I've tried `floatrow` and `subfig` - see edit.

Comment: @ted You can do those with subcaption too. But it's just a general suggestion. Of course I don't try to make you switch from one to another. `caption` is very common so better keep in mind that `caption` has the natural (from the same author) satellite `subcaption` package if `floatrow` starts causing trouble.

Comment: @percusse well I am open minded, I thought I "simply" pick the most powerfull package. WHile those are harder to learn, they usually are more comfortable once you know your way arround. This seemed to be `floatrow`, and since it claims to be compatible with `caption`, I assume that I am missing some include/pretext. I am sorry if I came of as offended.

Comment: @crowley I have issues with the jump targets using your solution, after several latex runs thay still point to the wrong chapter. I will see if i can put together a mwe

Comment: I accepted your awnser, my issue came from the fact that the template I was using used `picins`, when I commented it out the hyperlinks work as expected