# Figures: What is the difference between using subfig or subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats

I tend to use `\subfloats[]{}` in my figures when I want to list multiple labelled figures of similar content in one bigger picture.  However, I see that some people use `\subfigure`.

> What is the difference between these two options?
>
> Is one better than the other?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width= 2in]{something}}\\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width= 2in]{something}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfigure[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}}\\
\subfigure[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Since [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure) is two years old, does Axel's solution still apply?  By this I mean, has nothing changed with `subfig`?  Are there only 2 'biased' pros for the use of `subfig`?

Is the outcome still it is more advisable to use `subcaption` over `subfig` where I am using the latter `subfig`?

Comment: I would add `floatrow` and `subcaption` into that list.

Comment: you might want to consider that `subfig` is intended to replace `subfigure`, although it may not be fully backward compatible.  `subfigure` is deprecated for use in new documents.

Comment: Obligatory link [Subfig vs. Subcaption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure)

Comment: @percusse so the only reason is `hyperref`.  Then in the second solution, the author mentions the use of `\subcaption` over `\subfloat`.  So I guess I should add that as argument to OP about which one is truly the best or most appropriate to use, no?

Comment: @dustin Read Axel's (the author of `caption`, `subcaption` ...) very last comment at the end. Also (O)riginal (P)oster is you :-) There is never a truly best. It's all temporal opinions.

Comment: @karlkoeller -- when i referred to `subfig` and `subfigure`, i meant the packages.  i believe that both define the command `\subfigure`; i don't know where a `\subfig` command might be defined, and suspect it might not exist in any well known package.

Answer (score 52):

The question now seems a bit clearer.

I can give you a very simple answer which can be found anywhere.
This is from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure)

> Package `subfigure` – Deprecated: Figures divided into subfigures
>
> The pack­age is now con­sid­ered ob­so­lete: it was su­per­seded by `sub­fig`, but users may find the more re­cent `sub­cap­tion` pack­age more sat­is­fac­tory.

Also considered that the latest versions of both `subfigure` and `subfig` have been released in 2005, while the latest version of `subcaption` has been released a few months ago, you can make your conclusions.

Answer (score 36):

As you can read on the corresponding CTAN entries, [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) and [`subfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfloat): **The [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package replaces the [`sub­fig­ure`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) pack­age.**

---

Here are examples taken from the corresponding manual:

Example using the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package:

```
\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfloat[First.]{...}\qquad
\subfloat[Second figure.]{...}\\
\subfloat[Third.]{\label{3figs-c}...}%
\caption{Three sub-floats.}
\label{3figs}
\end{figure}
```

Example using the [`subfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfloat) package:

```
\begin{subfigures}
\label{fig:fig1a2}
%
\begin{figure}\centering
\fbox{fig. 1}
\caption{This is the first figure}\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}\centering
\fbox{fig. 2}
\caption{This is the second figure}\label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}
%
\end{subfigures}
```

However, in my [PhD thesis](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/?id=1145031) I used the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package together with [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package which worked very well.

Here's my preample:

```
\usepackage[%
    font={small,sf},
    labelfont=bf,
    format=hang,    
    format=plain,
    margin=0pt,
    width=0.8\textwidth,
]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
```

When I wanted to put two pictures side by side I used this template:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox[Short Subcaption]{%
    Subcaption%
    \label{subfig:sublabel1}%
}
[%
    0.45\textwidth % width of caption
]%
{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]%
    {picture1.jpg}%
}%
\hspace{0.1\textwidth} % seperation
\subcaptionbox[Short Subcaption]{%
    Subcaption%
    \label{subfig:sublabel2}%
}
[%
    0.45\textwidth % width of caption
]%
{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]%
    {picture2.jpg}%
}%
\caption[Short Caption]{Caption}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```

You see that in this example the widths add up to 100 % (45 subpic + 10 sep + 45 subpic = 100).

### Update (subcaption)

Using `\hfill` so separate the different subfigures is a better way than the `\hspace{0.1\textwidth}` approach (see [subcaption: Calculating the Width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361579/)). In addition I made the code more compact and used images that are available on a normal LaTeX system by default.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: The template with subcaption wasn't working for me, I commented the hspace and it's working now. Thank you for your templates, very handy.