# Two figures on the same line

Tags: floats

I am trying to get two pictures on the same line in LaTeX. I found some example on the Internet that works very well but there is some strange black frame around the pictures. Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]\centering
   \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
     \frame{\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{RL.png}}
     \caption{Interpolation for Data 1}\label{Fig:Data1}
   \end{minipage}
   \begin {minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
     \frame{\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{RC1.png}}
     \caption{Interpolation for Data 2}\label{Fig:Data2}
   \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

What can I do to remove them?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Delete the surrounding `\frame{...}` from your code; `\frame` is a kernel command which draws a tight frame around its argument.

Use `\centering` inside each `minipage` to center each image inside it, and optionally use `\hfill` between them; in this case, the external `\centering` is not required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
   \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
     \caption{Interpolation for Data 1}\label{Fig:Data1}
   \end{minipage}\hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
     \caption{Interpolation for Data 2}\label{Fig:Data2}
   \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Gonzalo Medina` happy to hear from you after some gap...

Answer (score 8):

Another solution can be achieved with these lines:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}} 
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}} 
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}}
    \caption{(a) blah (b) blah (c) blah (d) blah}
    \label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
```

And the result will be:

[image]

If you change `width=0.24\textwidth` for  `width=0.5\textwidth`, the images will be re-distributed automatically:

[image]

The original answer comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628649/multiple-subfigures-in-a-row-in-a-latex-document). It is always useful to have multiple options on the same page!
Of course, there are more options like multiple sub-caption etc. For more information, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314/figures-what-is-the-difference-between-using-subfig-or-subfigure).

Comment: Add to preamble `\usepackage{subfigure}`

Comment: subfigure is deprecated and should no longer be used, see https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure

Comment: Could you please tell us the up-to-date alternative of `subfigure`?

Comment: You could use `subcaption`

Comment: Is there any way to adjust the distance between two images?