# Getting error with \usepackage{subfigure} when it is used with \usepackage{subcaption} at the same time in one document

Tags: packages, subfloats, subcaption

I used following solution : ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540197/148579 ) in order to put multiple figures next to each other only in a single line.

But, I received following error:

Apparently, `\usepackage{subfigure}` cannot be used at the same time with `\usepackage{subcaption}` that I need it as well.

**RECEIVED ERROR :**

> **Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation(subcaption) with the subfigure package. \begin{document}**

This one one I did (exactly similar the proposed mentioned solution):

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{Part_1_in_Figure}} 
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{Part_2_in_Figure}} 
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{Part_3_in_Figure}}
\caption{(a) blah (b) blah (c) blah}
\label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you to propose a solution to fix this error, or completely another solution.

Comment: The simplest solution: *Just don't load the `subfigure` package*. It's buggy and badly deprecated. Why are you trying to use it? You can place multiple subfigures next to each with the machinery of the `subcaption` package alone; you do *not* need the `subfigure` package to get this job done.

Comment: @Micro, Yes, apparently it is a goods solution. I selected it as I sew the inserted images in the answer such as I was expected the same output.  Could you please present me other better alternative solutions with the same result. Thanks

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, and do please mention which document class you use. (Not all subfigure-related packages are compatible with all document classes.)

Comment: @Mico , I added what I did by editing the question. (\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how the OP's code might be re-cast in terms of macros provided by the `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[bla bla]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textwidth]{Part_1_in_Figure}}\hfill 
\subfloat[blb blb]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textwidth]{Part_2_in_Figure}}\hfill
\subfloat[blc blc]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textwidth]{Part_3_in_Figure}}
\caption{Overall figure caption}
\label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```