# Place two Lilypond examples side by side

Tags: music, sidebyside

I need help here: I am trying to place two Lilypond musical examples side-by-side. How can I achieve that?
Any help is appreciated.

This is the code I am using:

```
\usepackage{float}  
...
\begin{document}  
...  
  \begin{minipage}  
      \begin{example}  
       \centering  
\begin{lilypond}[staffsize=12]

Musical Example 1 comes here

\end{lilypond}
      \caption{Caption 1} 
      \label{ex1}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}  
      \begin{example}  
       \centering  
\begin{lilypond}[staffsize=12]

Musical Example 2 comes here

\end{lilypond}
      \caption{Caption 2} 
      \label{ex2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

By the way, TexShop with the Lilypond-Book implementation is a life saver!

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314/figures-what-is-the-difference-between-using-subfig-or-subfigure/122329

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE is missing some information, but this seems to work fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{lilypond}[fragment]
            c4
        \end{lilypond}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{lilypond}[fragment]
            c4
        \end{lilypond}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(Compiled with `lilypond-book --output=out --pdf file.lytex`, `cd out`, and `pdflatex file.tex`.)

[image]

Comment: This solution works fine, except I can't get captions for both musical examples. Thank you, though.

Comment: @Lotto In that case, you may want to unaccept my answer and accept Tiuri's answer instead.

Answer (score 5):

Typesetting two lilypond examples side by side with the option of giving captions to them (that seems to be important for you) can easily be done with the `subfigure` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[First example.]{\begin{lilypond}[fragment]
        c4
    \end{lilypond}}
    \hspace{0.1\textwidth}
    \subfigure[Second example.]{\begin{lilypond}[fragment]
        c4
    \end{lilypond}}
    \caption{Here are two music examples.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to have a common caption for the two examples together, but rather treat them caption-wise as seperate figures, you can stick with Richard's solution and just add `\caption` beneath both examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{lilypond}[fragment]
            c4
        \end{lilypond}
        \caption{First example.}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{lilypond}[fragment]
            c4
        \end{lilypond}
        \caption{Second example.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]