# Place two LilyPond examples side by side in LaTeX

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to place two LilyPond musical examples side-by-side in a LaTeX document, with captions. How can I achieve that?

This is the code I am using:

```
\usepackage{float}  
...
\begin{document}  
...  
  \begin{minipage}  
      \begin{example}  
       \centering  
\begin{lilypond}[staffsize=12]

Musical Example 1 comes here

\end{lilypond}
      \caption{Caption 1} 
      \label{ex1}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}  
      \begin{example}  
       \centering  
\begin{lilypond}[staffsize=12]

Musical Example 2 comes here

\end{lilypond}
      \caption{Caption 2} 
      \label{ex2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

By the way, TeXShop with the LilyPond-Book implementation is a life saver!

Comment: Well, it was a question about a writting music excerpts in a DMA dissertation. Sorry if I cause any trouble,..

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies for posting this answer both here *and* at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369115/place-two-lilypond-examples-side-by-side/), but I wanted to be thorough. Please don't upvote.)

Your MWE is missing some information, but this seems to work fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{lilypond}[fragment]
            c4
        \end{lilypond}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{lilypond}[fragment]
            c4
        \end{lilypond}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(Compiled with `lilypond-book --output=out --pdf file.lytex`, `cd out`, and `pdflatex file.tex`.)

[image]