# Four figures in one row in Overleaf

Tags: subfloats

I would like to add four figures into a single row but I am unable to do it. I tried a lot to figure out the error but still failed. At the moment, there is one figure on row 1, the second figure on row two, third figure and fourth figure are on row 4.

```
\begin{figure}
%\centering
    %\hfill
    \subfigure[Training         loss]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{images/all_vits.pdf}}

    %\vspace{-4pt}
    %\hfill
    \subfigure[Accuracy]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{images/acc_vit.pdf}}
   %
    %\vspace{-4pt}
    %\hfill
    %\caption{Comparison of pure ViTs and Convolutional ViTs %models.}
    %\vspace{-13pt}
    %\label{fig:ALLVITS}
%\end{figure}
%\begin{figure}

    %\hfill
    \subfigure[Training loss]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{images/ours_loss.pdf}}
    %\vspace{-4pt}
    %\hfill
    \subfigure[Accuracy]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{images/ours_acc.pdf}}
    %\vspace{-4pt}
    %\hfill
    %\caption{Comparison of our module integrates in O-PVT.}
    \label{fig:OPVT}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Make sure that there are no blank lines after each `\subfigure` in your code; comment them out or delete them

Comment: Here are some examples? [Figures: What is the difference between using subfig or subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314/figures-what-is-the-difference-between-using-subfig-or-subfigure)

Comment: Please be aware that the `sub­fig­ure` package is obsolete and you should use the `subfig` package instead, see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure.

Comment: Next time, please provide a MWE. You can take my code as an example.

Answer (score 4):

For more information see [Figures: What is the difference between using subfig or subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314/). Make sure that the sum of the width is less than 100 %. BTW, your code looks kind of messy. I recommend keeping it tidy, see the proposal below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[First.]{\label{4figs-a} \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}% The "%" masks the line break.
\hfill
\subfloat[Second.]{\label{4figs-b} \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[Third.]{\label{4figs-c} \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[Forth.]{\label{4figs-d} \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\caption{Four sub-floats.}
\label{4figs}
\end{figure}

See \figurename~\ref{4figs-b} and \figurename~\ref{4figs-d}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now, four figures are in one row but it gives an error "LaTeX Error: No counter 'subfigure@save' defined." Also, on the next page, the gap between the caption and table is overlap each other.

Comment: This is why you need to provide a better MWE. Otherwise, we cannot know your situation.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the below code is worked fine.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \subfigure[Training loss curves]{\includegraphics[width=0.245\linewidth]{images/all.pdf}}
    \subfigure[Accuracy curves]{\includegraphics[width=0.245\linewidth]{images/all.pdf}}
    \label{fig:ALLVITS}
    \subfigure[Training loss curves]{\includegraphics[width=0.245\linewidth]{images/all.pdf}}
    \subfigure[Accuracy curves]{\includegraphics[width=0.245\linewidth]{images/all.pdf}}
    \caption{Comparison of our module integrates in O-PVT.}
    \label{fig:OPVT}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Could you please add more details to your answer? You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When posting questions and answers, please provide MWEs https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that