# Multiple subfigures show under the page instead of on the next page

Tags: floats, page, size

I have used the following to show five figures, but there are two problems which I think happen because the total size of all five figures is too large.

First, the figures are not placed exactly where I want them (they go at the beginning of the next page). Second, the rest of them aren't placed on the next page but under the current page! I don't have these problems with just a single image.

[image]

The code:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \subfigure[Weak]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{fab reg_overall_initial_b0.jpg}\label{img02a}}
        \subfigure[Weak]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{fab reg_overall_initial_b28.jpg}\label{img02b}}
        \subfigure[Weak]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{fab reg_overall_initial_b50.jpg}\label{img02c}}
        \subfigure[Weak]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{fab reg_overall_initial_b732.jpg}\label{img02d}}
        \subfigure[Weak]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{fab reg_overall_initial_b1.jpg}\label{img02e}}
    \end{center}
    \caption{different types: \subref{img02a} O \subref{img02b} S \subref{img02c} W \subref{img02d} D \subref{img02e} A}
    \label{fig02}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Why don't you just make the images smaller so that the images fit? Maybe I do not get the question :).

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314, if you use the **sub­fig­ure** package, be aware that the **subfig** package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) replaces the **sub­fig­ure** pack­age (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure, "The package is now considered obsolete")

Comment: Please provide a working (compilable) code so that we can see which packages you're using. You seem to be using `subfigure`, which was obsoleted a long time ago. Also, since you're using the H placement option, you mostly prevent LaTeX from moving the figures to fit the page.

Comment: I dont make images smaller because I need to show the detail

Comment: The main problem is that you cannot split a float across two pages.  OTOH, you can treat multiple floats as if they were one float using `\ContinuedFloat` (capton packaged).  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages

Comment: Don't use the `H` position! This might not fix the issue at hand, but `H` leads to unpleasant pagination, if you use it you'll have to fine tune all positioning manually if you want pleasant typography. It's much easier (and usually better) to let LaTeX decide and stick to the default placement of floats.

Comment: `figure` makes a box so no text within a `figure` will break over a page. Also the only function of a `figure` environmnt is to allow that text to move, so if you don't want it to move, and do want to allow page breaking, not using `figure` is probably the simplest option.