# Caption automatically centered in a REVTeX document

Tags: captions, revtex

I'm recently writing an APS paper with REVTeX and encountered a problem. The captions in all figure and table floats are automatically centered instead of being fully justified. I tried `\captionsetup` but there are only options like `raggedright` or `raggedleft`. Can anyone tell me what I was missing? The following is the header of my document:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,reprint,twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb,groupedaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
```

A typical figure environment is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{FIG11.eps}
            \label{fig:FIG11}
    \end{subfigure}~       
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{FIG12.eps}
            \label{fig:FIG12}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Gate control when large magnitude control is allowed. (a) Z-gate control in Lorentzian-like environment. (b) Identity-gate control in Ohmic environment. Here $\epsilon(t)\leq20\omega_{0}$. }
    \label{fig: large control}        
\end{figure}
```

The strange thing is that there is a sample "apssamp.tex" in the REVTeX zip file provided by APS. I copy my figure environment and paste it into the sample file and the caption is fully justified. But if I copy a figure environment in the sample and paste it to my own tex file, I always get centered caption. That's why I suspect that the problem should be due to the header.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I don't think the pre is where the problem is - we should see you `figure` environment as well.  I can confirm that it doesn't do that for me.

Comment: As far as I know, `caption` is not compatible with `revtex4-1`. For subfloats, I think `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` is better.

Comment: @egreg, good spot - I've never used RevTeX for anything where subfigures are accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the template again with the                 subfigure package and got what I want. Although I'm still not clear what exactly caused the trouble in my original code but it's all settled now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try removing unnecessary packages. Also you have defined graphicx package two times. This might be causing problem.

Answer (score 15):

The `caption` package is not compatible with `revtex4-1`; you can still add captioned subfloats with

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

in the preamble and a syntax such as

```
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:FIG11}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{FIG11.eps}%
}
```

In the optional argument of `\subfloat` you can supply also a subcaption; if empty, only the markers `(a)` `(b)` and so on will appear.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.