# RevTeX 4.1 caption issues

Tags: revtex

I am using REVTeX 4.1 but it doesn't seem to be 'in effect'. One thing I noticed is that captions are not justified and the font is not smaller as it should be. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps,prl,twocolumn ,groupedaddress,nobibnotes]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off,}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{circuits.png}
\caption{This is a long sentence to test whether the caption is justified
 or not. Unfortunately it is not.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If using revtex for a journal submission you should let it handle captions, not redefine the caption handling with caption package.

Comment: I removed the caption package and the captions are still not justified...

Comment: I know, but each revtex using journal specifies the caption formatting it needs, if you are submitting to one of those, don't change it, if not, why use revtex? Journal class files are not intended to be customisable, they are designed to enforce a journal style.

Comment: From looking at all papers published in that journal, I know that they want the caption to be in smaller font and justified. I am using that journal in my document class options, still it is not working.

Comment: Journals do not always use the same style for publication as submission, same advice applies in any case, there is no point using a publisher specified style template then changing the style.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle REVTeX does a pretty good job with many complex things like two columns etc.  It is also suitable for submission to other journals (i.e. Nature Communications) which do not provide a style (as they will completely revamp formatting as you say).  A use case is that one might like to customize the way the preprint looks for arXiv submission, etc.

Comment: @mforbes naturally, especially the original version, check the `Original version` comment at the top of the `.cls` file:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed the behavior you've described is the default in `revtex4-1`.

This isn't "in effect", as you said, just because you're loading the `caption` package, which is incompatible with that class.

So, don't load either `caption` nor `subcaption` and you will have your captions in a `\small` font and justified.

MWE

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps,prl,twocolumn ,groupedaddress,nobibnotes]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{circuits.png}
\caption{This is a long sentence to test whether the caption is justified
 or not. Unfortunately it is not.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT (in response to the OP's comment)

`minipage`s are not incompatible with `revtex4-1`.

Here's an example of how to have two images side by side, in one column and in two columns mode.

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps,prl,twocolumn ,groupedaddress,nobibnotes]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{circuits.png}
\caption{This is a long sentence to test whether the caption is justified
 or not. Unfortunately it is not.}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{circuits.png}
\caption{Another figure.}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{circuits.png}
\caption{This is a long sentence to test whether the caption is justified
 or not. Unfortunately it is not.}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{circuits.png}
\caption{Another figure.}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Output (two images in the same column)

[image]

Output (two images spanning two columns)

[image]

Comment: But then I can't have two figures side by side (unless I use minipage, which again might be incompatible, and so on)

Comment: @student1 `minipage`s are not incompatible. See the edit.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem as OP: centered captions in the wrong font size. The problem was my use of the package `subfig`. The solution is to add the following option:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

See [Caption automatically centered in a REVTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135718/caption-automatically-centered-in-a-revtex-document).