# How to get justified subcaptions with \subfloat in revtex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subfloats, revtex, subfig

I know that the documentclass `revtex4-1` is incompatible with the `caption` (and `subcaption`) package and thus when using the [`subfig`](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/drift/stud/subfig.pdf) package I need to add the option `[caption=false]` as elaborated by [karlkoeller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227281/132742) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169803/132742).

However, even with the option `[caption=false]` I still get subcaptions that are not justified. The main caption is nicely justified, but long subcaptions are not. On the other hand, changing the justification to `[justification=raggedright]` works as expected. Also with `\documentclass{article}` things are fine.

**Any way of making long _sub_captions justified in `revtex4-1`?**

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prd]{revtex4-1}
% \documentclass{article}  % works with docclass article but not with revtex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,justification=justified]{subfig}  
% raggedright works, justified does not
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[htb]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Long text here. Long text here. Long irregular text here. 
    More irregular text here. Long text here. Broken up with some other words. 
    Trying to show the ragged effect left and right. 
    Addsomeveryextremelylongwords tomakethingsworse andthus moreclear.]
    {\missingfigure[figwidth=5cm]{}}
    \hspace{1cm}
    \subfloat[Long text here. Long text here. Long irregular text here. 
    More irregular text here. Long text here. Broken up with some other words. 
    Trying to show the ragged effect left and right. 
    Addsomeveryextremelylongwords tomakethingsworse andthus moreclear.]
    {\missingfigure[figwidth=5cm]{}}
    \caption{Large caption spanning both subfigures. 
    This caption actually is justified as it is supposed to be. 
    Unfortunately the same does not go for the subcaptions above 
    which are not justified. Using ``raggedright'' in the captionsetup 
    actually works also on the subcaptions. ``justified'' however does not.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure they are supposed to be justified?

Comment: On page 16 of the [REVTeX 4.1 Author's Guide](https://cdn.journals.aps.org/files/revtex/auguide4-1.pdf) it only says very generally: "Captions less than one line long are centered under the figure, otherwise they span the width of the figure."

It says nothing about subcaptions explicitly, so I'd have thought subcaptions should be justified as well.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `caption=false` option, `subfig` loads the `caption3` package for configuration. This package defines the various possible justification styles. However, have a look at how `justified` is defined, as opposed to the others:

```tex
\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{centering}{\centering}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{centerfirst}{\centerfirst}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{centerlast}{\centerlast}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{raggedleft}{\raggedleft}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{raggedright}{\raggedright}
```

So the package just assumes that justification is the default anyway and therefore does not do anything to enforce it - which appears to be wrong when using REVTeX.

The solution is simple. Just overwrite the declaration afterwards to automatically re-justify:

```tex
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % loads caption3
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for the \justifying macro
\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{\justifying}
```

Since the default option of `subfig` is to use `justified` anyway, all we needed to do was to fix its definition.

Comment: I've encountered this issue for a while and this is the most to-the-point one. Should receive more attention.

Answer (score 0):

For whom might end up here looking for an answer

Note that `revtex` provides the commads `\onecolumngrid` and `\twocolumngrid`. From my experience they help dealing with floats that require two columns.

Here is possible solution that at least takes it close to the `justified` option:

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prd]{revtex4-1}
% \documentclass{article}  % works with docclass article but not with revtex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false, justification=centerlast]{subfig}
% raggedright works, justified does not
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\onecolumngrid% Mind one empty line below

\begin{figure}[htb]
    % \centering
    \subfloat[Long text here. Long text here. Long irregular text here.
    More irregular text here. Long text here. Broken up with some other words.
    Trying to show the ragged effect left and right.
    Addsomeveryextremelylongwords tomakethingsworse andthus moreclear.]
    {\missingfigure[figwidth=5cm]{}}
    \hspace{1cm}
    \subfloat[Long text here. Long text here. Long irregular text here.
    More irregular text here. Long text here. Broken up with some other words.
    Trying to show the ragged effect left and right.
    Addsomeveryextremelylongwords tomakethingsworse andthus moreclear.]
    {\missingfigure[figwidth=5cm]{}}
    \caption{Large caption spanning both subfigures.
    This caption actually is justified as it is supposed to be.
    Unfortunately the same does not go for the subcaptions above
    which are not justified. Using ``raggedright'' in the captionsetup
    actually works also on the subcaptions. ``justified'' however does not.}
\end{figure}
\twocolumngrid

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: two subfigures side by side with justified captions below them]

If you are trying to use `subfloat` or `phantomcaption` in `revtex`, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557032/119017) might help you.