# Fully justify caption in RevTex 4-2

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, revtex

I'm writing a paper with REVTeX 4.2 using Overleaf and want the captions of my figures to be fully justified, but they are automatically centering. I've read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135718/caption-automatically-centered-in-a-revtex-document) about the same problem in RevTex 4.1, but I'm wondering if there's a way to full justify my captions with the regular figure and table environments without using \subfloat. The figure and table environments are automatically numbered, so I won't need to renumber everything if I want to add a figure to the beginning of the document.

I've also tried `\usepackage{caption}` with  `\captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}`, but that didn't work.

The header and an example figure for my document are below:

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,floatfix]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tiny, center, uppercase]{titlesec}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{3pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}

...
...

\begin{figure}[t!]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{experimental_diagram.jpg}
    \caption{Experimental setup. This diagram shows...}
    \label{fig:experiment_setup}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note the warning printed `Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.`  so the caption package will do nothing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use caption package but you could disable the centre-single line check in other ways.

[image]

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,floatfix]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tiny, center, uppercase]{titlesec}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{3pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}

...
...

\begin{figure}[t!]
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \makeatletter\long\def\@ifdim#1#2#3{#2}\makeatother
    \caption{Experimental setup. This diagram shows... }
    \label{fig:experiment_setup}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!