# Multiple \label commands before \ref

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, subfloats

I have tried several approaches to solve my problem but unfortunately none successful yet. I can not find documentation mentioning how to solve this particular case. My problem is that I am using a `subfigure` in `beamer` and I am trying to create multiple `\ref` points before the `\label` appear in the same figure. When compiling the `.tex` document only one reference point appears and the rest are appearing as ??. Is there any possible solution to my problem?

EDIT: The code I'm using

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\mode<presentation>
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\begin{columns}[t] 
\begin{column}[T]{5cm} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item<+-| alert@+> 1~\autoref{1} 
\item<+-| alert@+> 2~\autoref{2} etc 
\end{itemize} 
\end{column} 
\begin{column}[T]{5cm} 
\begin{figure} 
\only<1>{\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth} 
         \caption{sub caption 1} 
         \label{1} 
         \includegraphics[width=7.0cm,height=5cm]{fig 1} 
         \end{subfigure} } 
\only<2>{\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth} 
         \caption{sub caption 2} 
         \label{2} 
         \includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=5cm]{fig 2} 
         \end{subfigure} }
\caption{main} 
\protect\label{3} 
\end{figure} 
\end{column} 
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you please supply us with example code?

Comment: did you run the document at least two times?

Comment: Also kind of mandatory reading : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure

Comment: Dear all thank you for reply to my question.

<code>

Comment: Thank you all.
<code>
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}[T]{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item<+-| alert@+> 1~\autoref{1}
\item<+-| alert@+> 2~\autoref{2}
etc
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[T]{5cm} 
\begin{figure}
\only<1>{\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
\caption{c}
\label{1}
\includegraphics[width=7.0cm,height=5cm]{fig 1}
\end{subfigure}
}
\only<2>{\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
\caption{caption 2} \label{2}
\includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=5cm]{fig 2}
\end{subfigure}
}
etc
\caption{main} \protect\label{3}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

Comment: I should also mention that I am using this packages:

\usepackage{hyperref} %\Url Links
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{caption} %caption for figures
\usepackage{subcaption} %subfigures

Again thank you in advance for your time and effort replying to my question.

Comment: @percusse I did read similar documents, this is why I am applying sub captions etc. I can not understand why it only reads one `\label` and the rest are ignored.

@Herbert I did run the document twice...but the problem is that it only reads only one `\label`, the first one, the rest are ignored.

Comment: @MaxGraves my apologies that the code is not in a readable format but I do not know how to past it in the correct order. Thanks in advance for everybody assistance.

Comment: I've added your code into your question. Please check it further and complete it such that it starts with `\documentclass` and up to `\end{document}` with the necessary packages to replicate the problem. You can use the edit button under the question to add the details.

Comment: @percusse Thank you for your assistance. I have just added all necessary packets and I tested the code on my system it compiles and executes. Unfortunately only the first figure it appears as `1a` the second produces `??`. Thank you again for your time and effort.

Comment: Nothing to do with `subfigure`: I'll take a look at the `beamer` code and see if I can understand this a bit more

Comment: @JosephWright since `subfigure` can only see one reference point and miss the rest, you think is a problem with `beamer`? I appreciate that you spend some time with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you only show one subfigure per slide the counter of both subfigures is `a` which leads to problem with the labels. As a workaround to this problem, you can make the subcaption invisible instead and introduce an additional phantom caption:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\mode<presentation>
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\begin{columns}[t] 
\begin{column}[T]{5cm} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item<+-| alert@+> 1~\ref{1} 
\item<+-| alert@+> 2~\ref{2} etc 
\end{itemize} 
\end{column} 
\begin{column}[T]{5cm} 
\begin{figure}%
    \only<1>{%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}%
        \caption{sub caption 1}\label{1}%
            \includegraphics<1>[width=3cm]{example-image-a}%
        \end{subfigure}%
    }%
        \only<2>{{\phantomsubcaption}}%
    \visible<2>{%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}%
          \caption{sub caption 2}\label{2}%
            \includegraphics<2>[width=3cm]{example-image-b}%
        \end{subfigure}%
    }
    \caption{main} 
    \label{3} 
\end{figure} 
\end{column} 
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @samcarter I will compile it and test it. The idea sounds great. Thank you for your time and effort reading and approaching my problem.

Comment: @Thanos I just fixed a little bug, please see my updated code.

Comment: works perfectly. Thanks for all of your effort.