# Cross-referencing issue with subcaption in beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

Thank you in advance and support that provides this website for the tex users. I am a new member of the tex society almost a year now and I can say that most of my answers related to my problems have been answered previously here. Your work is really impressing taken in consideration that people are sharing knowledge for free.

Recently I came across with a problem that I think it is a bug of the system. I was trying to create a beamer presentation and by using `\usepackage{subcaption}` and `\begin{subfigure}` environment. While I was trying to use the `\label` and `\ref` points to my *subfigure(s)* I noticed that only the first `\label` was operating correctly as *1a*. Unfortunately the rest are coming up as *??*. I assume this is because the `\ref` points are located before the `\label`, but in this case all of them should not be operating correctly all should fail.

I was not able to find an answer relative to my question no matter how much I searched for. Maybe it is a bug of the system. I was just hopping that you could provide more information and maybe a solution to overcome this problem.

More information and the testing code can be found here: [Multiple \label commands before \ref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137149/multiple-label-commands-before-ref).

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\mode<presentation>
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\begin{columns}[t] 
\begin{column}[T]{5cm} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item<+-| alert@+> 1~\autoref{1} 
\item<+-| alert@+> 2~\autoref{2} etc 
\end{itemize} 
\end{column} 
\begin{column}[T]{5cm} 
\begin{figure} 
\only<1>{\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth} 
         \caption{sub caption 1} 
         \label{1} 
         \includegraphics[width=7.0cm,height=5cm]{fig 1} 
         \end{subfigure} } 
\only<2>{\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth} 
         \caption{sub caption 2} 
         \label{2} 
         \includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=5cm]{fig 2} 
         \end{subfigure} }
\caption{main} 
\protect\label{3} 
\end{figure} 
\end{column} 
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As it stands, I don't see how this new question adds anything to the existing one: can you elaborate?

Comment: @Jubobs The testing code is on the hyperlink but off course I can re posted here. I just do not want to duplicate the code.

Comment: On this site, we tend to prefer self-contained posts; it'd be great if you posted the code here rather than simply linking to it.

Comment: @Jubobs Perfect thank for providing advices, I have just added the code. Again thank you for your support.

Comment: But... wait.... That's exactly the same code as in that question you link to. I agree with Joseph: how is your question any different from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137149/multiple-label-commands-before-ref?

Comment: @Jubobs It is not a different question I thought that since there is not possible solution to my question on the previous post maybe this question should be reported as a bug. This is the reason that I reported here. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: From the `beamer` manual: "If you find no answers there, or if you are sure you have found a bug in beamer, please report it via bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issues." Similarly other package manuals will usually tell where to report bugs on them.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you for your advice. I was planning to report this as a bug but, before I do I was thinking about asking everyone here who know a lot about *LaTeX*. I suppose after a few days if there is no response I should report it. Thank you all for your time and effort assisting me in my problem.