# 2 Tikz, 1 Figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I would like to include 2 Tikz into one figure and caption each of the Tikz. I've explored `subfigure` but that did not seem to work. I'm trying to have the two diagrams appear side-by-side with a caption under each diagram. I appreciate any help rendered.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      height=8cm,
      width=6cm,
      bar width=15pt,
      xlabel={$c$},
      ylabel={Number of primes},
      ymin=0,
      ytick=\empty,
      xtick=data,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge x limits=0.2,
      symbolic x coords={0,1,2},
      xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}
    ]
      \addplot[fill=white] coordinates {
        (0,295)
        (1,175)
        (2,20)
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{40-bit primes} \label{40bits}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      height=8cm,
      width=7cm,
      bar width=15pt,
      xlabel={$c$},
      ylabel={Number of primes},
      ymin=0,
      ytick=\empty,
      xtick=data,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge x limits=0.2,
      symbolic x coords={0,1,2,3,4},
      xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}
    ]
      \addplot[fill=white] coordinates {
        (0,182)
        (1,215)
        (2,75)
        (3,17)
        (4,1)
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{41-bit primes} \label{41bits}
```

Comment: Why not use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead? See [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure)

Comment: @Adam May I know which packages are they found in?

Comment: Those are the names of the packages. `subcaption` is probably the best to use, as it is actively maintained.

Comment: @Adam I've tried `subfigure` by naively enclosing `tikzpicture` and its caption into `\begin{subfigure}` and `\end{subfigure}`, but that didn't work. The complain is: `Missing \endscname`.

Comment: If you want a diagnosis for that, I would need to see a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), but, at any rate, I've provided an answer to your question that I think is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possibility that makes use of the `\subcaption` command of the `subcaption` package and the `minipage` environment (see p. 4 of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/subcaption.pdf); there are also dedicated `subfigure` and `subtable` environments that are explained on p. 5, if you prefer another possibility).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      height=8cm,
      width=6cm,
      bar width=15pt,
      xlabel={$c$},
      ylabel={Number of primes},
      ymin=0,
      ytick=\empty,
      xtick=data,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge x limits=0.2,
      symbolic x coords={0,1,2},
      xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}
    ]
      \addplot[fill=white] coordinates {
        (0,295)
        (1,175)
        (2,20)
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{40-bit primes}\label{40bits}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      height=8cm,
      width=7cm,
      bar width=15pt,
      xlabel={$c$},
      ylabel={Number of primes},
      ymin=0,
      ytick=\empty,
      xtick=data,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge x limits=0.2,
      symbolic x coords={0,1,2,3,4},
      xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}
    ]
      \addplot[fill=white] coordinates {
        (0,182)
        (1,215)
        (2,75)
        (3,17)
        (4,1)
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{41-bit primes} \label{41bits}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit

In response your question in the comment section, you can change the appearance of the `\subcaption` formatting by renewing `\thesubfigure` command and by making use of the `\captionsetup` command.

To achieve the result you want, add

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{Fig~\thefigure(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple}
```

to your preamble.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help @Adam, one last question though, how can I label the captions Fig 1(a) and Fig 1(b) for example?

Comment: @BlackAdder see my update