# how to put odd number subfigures in multiple rows

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

There are five figures. Basically, I'd like them to displayed as following:

```
     |figure 1|figure 2|

|figure 3|figure 4|figure 5|
```

The first two figures are in the first row and the last three are in the second row. And
The first row should be in the middle of the second row.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>(Updated to include @Mico's suggestion of a `\bigskip`.)</sup>

Here's one possibility that makes use of `\parbox`es. This solution makes sense, I think, if you want all of the figures to have a figure number that increases.

You can change the length for the first two `\parbox`es and the length for the first two `\includegraphics` commands if you want the top two figures to be smaller and not span the entire width of the overall `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\parbox{.48\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}\caption{}}
\hfill
\parbox{.48\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}\caption{}}

\bigskip

\parbox{.32\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}\caption{}}
\hfill
\parbox{.32\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}\caption{}}
\hfill
\parbox{.32\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}\caption{}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are also the `subfig` and `subcaption` packages that allow you to have subfigures (*e.g.*, the labels will be something like Figure 1(a), Figure 1(b), *etc.*; see, for starters, [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure) and also [Jesse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165449/32888) for a concrete example).

Comment: You may want to insert a bit of extra vertical spacing, say `\medskip` or `\bigskip`, between the two groups of figures. Otherwise, it's not immediately clear where the first two captions belong.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the suggestion! Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is use of `subfigure` package with `subfigure` command.

Edit: Reminded by Adam, `subfigure` is depreciated, so a new update here `subfig` is used with `subfloat` command.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\centering
\subfloat[~subcaption1]{\includegraphics[scale=.95]{figure}}\,
\subfloat[~subcaption2]{\includegraphics[scale=.95]{figure}}
\\
\subfloat[~subcaption1]{\includegraphics[scale=.95]{figure}}\,
\subfloat[~subcaption2]{\includegraphics[scale=.95]{figure}}\,
\subfloat[~subcaption2]{\includegraphics[scale=.95]{figure}}
\vspace{-0.6 cm}  % can be changed to suit one's need.
\caption{Caption}
\label{}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the need for `\mbox`?

Comment: Indeed, it works without `\mbox`, but my gut feeling was that it is for horizontally aligned material said in wikibook here. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#makebox_and_mbox. With that in mind I keep it there. @karlkoeller, what do you reckon?

Comment: I would remove it. But feel free not to follow my opinion. :-)

Comment: @Jesse Those `\mbox` commands only add unwanted spaces (because you're not protecting end-of-lines). Also the lonely `[t]` in the options to `figure*` should be `[tp]`

Comment: @egreg, karlkoeller -- Thanks to you all. I finally understand the differences which had puzzled me since I posted it, not sure whether to keep or to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the graphs in `minipage` environments -- each one associated with a `\caption` command -- all within one and the same `figure` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit 'demo' option in real document
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

% first group of figures
\begin{minipage}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic1.pdf}
\caption{First of five} \label{fig:1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{3mm} % choose horizontal spacing to suit your needs
\begin{minipage}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic2.pdf}
\caption{Second of five} \label{fig:2}
\end{minipage}

% second group of figures
\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic3.pdf}
\caption{Third of five} \label{fig:3}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic4.pdf}
\caption{Fourth of five} \label{fig:4}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic5.pdf}
\caption{Last of five} \label{fig:5}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\end{document}
```