# Problem with Subfigure

Tags: subfloats

Could someone please tell me why this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics{ngc3242fullslitmag.png}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives this error message?

```
! Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7 \includegraphics
                    {ngc3242fullslitmag.png}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that \ entering the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What happens if you omit the `.png` extension?

Comment: Same error omitting the extension.

Comment: What about using `subfig` instead of `subfigure`? `subfigure` is a deprecated package. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure

Comment: In using subfig, I get undefined subfigure error. I changed subfigure to subfloat and get the original error.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what's going on, but putting a line break between `\begin{subfigure}` and `\includegraphics{...}` in the source code eliminates the error for me. This also solves the problem with `subfig`, too.

Comment: @AdamLiter - The `subfigure` environment takes a mandatory argument -- its intended width. Because that piece of information is missing in the OP's code, LaTeX ends up producing a near-incomprehensible error message...

Answer (score 5):

The `subfigure` environment is defined by the `subcaption` package. Importantly, it takes one *mandatory* argument -- the intended width. The following code works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} % not 'subfigure'

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{3in} % choose intended width here
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ngc3242fullslitmag.png}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, the `subfigure` package is seriously deprecated. Don't use it. You should work with either the `subcaption` (as above) or `subfig` package instead.