# RevTex4-1 caption behaviour for last line changed after customization, how to change it back?

Tags: floats, subcaption, revtex

I'm in the `\begin{figure*}` environment, with a few `subfigure` objects that have no captions. After `\end{subfigure}`, I'm currently using

```
\caption[]{\small\justify blah blah blah}
```

which produces the following image [image]

However, if I go to

```
\caption[]{\small blah blah blah}
```

after first setting

```
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[justification=justified,labelfont=large]{subcaption}
```

I get

[image]

which is what I want except the last line is centered. I want the last line to be as the first picture. Am I missing a really simple command? Thanks.

Total code:

```
 \begin{figure*}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
           \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.eps}  
            \label{fig:1}
\vspace{-12pt}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}  
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2.eps}
            \label{fig:2}
\vspace{-12pt}
        \end{subfigure}
 %       \vskip\baselineskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}   
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig3.eps}
            \label{fig:3}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}   
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig4.eps}
            \label{fig:4}
        \end{subfigure}
\vspace{-10pt}
        \caption[]{\small\justify blah blah blahblah blah}
\label{fig:plot}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Is this for a journal submission? If so, you don't need to adjust this type of setting.

Comment: Yes. Using Rev Tex 4-1. I'm under the impression I do though however.. Looking at that APS JAP papers, captions tend to be indented slightly but are justified throughout and hold the last line not be centered but left justified if its not a full line.

Comment: Regardless of your choice, I'm sure the journal editors will update content to match their requirements.

Comment: Doesn't my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `caption` and `subcaption` with `revtex4-1` because they have incompatibilities.

If you want to go on with it, load the package `subcaption` (which loads `caption`) without options and then load the package `ragged2e` and define

```
\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{\justifying}
```

At this point declare this setup

```
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=large}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{\justifying}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=large}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
           \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.eps}
            \label{fig:1}
\vspace{-12pt}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2.eps}
            \label{fig:2}
\vspace{-12pt}
        \end{subfigure}
 %       \vskip\baselineskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig3.eps}
            \label{fig:3}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig4.eps}
            \label{fig:4}
        \end{subfigure}
\vspace{-10pt}
        \caption[]{\small blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
                          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah}
\label{fig:plot}
\end{figure*} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]