# Why the `revtex4-1` class is incompatible with the `subcaption` package?

Tags: captions, revtex

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169803/1035) states that the `caption` package is not compatible with `revtex4-1`.

[Another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228384/1035) provides a workaround to make `caption` compatible with `revtex4-1` by using the `ragged2e` package.

It seems to me that the `\caption` command provided by `revtex4-1` is responsible for this. Can this incompatibility be fixed easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `caption` package needs to patch the commands `\caption`, `\@caption`, and `\@makecaption`, the first ones are defined by the LaTeX kernel (but sometimes overwritten by document classes like `revtex4-1`), and the latter one is defined by the document class.

Unfortunately there are no guidelines on how to patch internal LaTeX commands, and the concept "LaTeX packages" is only designed for packages which extends LaTeX without patching internal LaTeX code. So packages like `caption` cannot be implemented in a clean and compatible way, it's simply an impossible task.

Basically there are four different methods on how to patch existing commands anyway:

1. Save the old definition, and make the new definition use the old one, too.
2. Patch the command with `\patchcmd` (or a different command) offered by the `etoolbox` package.
3. Redefine the definition without saving and using the old one. But try to build-in as many definitions offered by document classes and/or other packages as possible.
4. Simply redefine the definition without saving and using the old one.

The method chosen deeply affects how compatible is your definition with other packages which either redefines the command, too, or rely on a specific behavior of that command. That's one of the many reasons why there are so many incompatibilities between different LaTeX packages resp. LaTeX document classes and packages.

The `caption` package used to use the method 1 until version 3.0. But since so many document classes and packages re-define `\caption` and `\@caption` itself this method has lead to a way which was not maintainable. So starting with version 3.1 the `caption` package uses method 3. And to make sure it does not overwrite any functionality it checks if `\caption`, `\@caption`, and `\@makecaption` are known before the redefinition takes place. If it finds an unknown definition it refuses to redefine `\caption` and `\@caption`, making sure that the `caption` package either works as expected or drops an `incompatible` message to the user, falling back to an "compatibility mode" offering only functionality which was already offered by version 1.0 of the package which did not patched `\caption`. (And since the `subcaption` package relies on the patched versions of `\caption` and `\@caption` it refuses to work at all.)

BTW: Luckily most LaTeX packages the `caption` package is adapted to are dead/unmaintained, otherwise it would take very much time to keep track of internal changes within these packages. Which basically means packages like `caption` could only be realized because most of the other LaTeX packages are already dead!

As consequence any document class (or package which redefines `\caption` or `\@caption`) is considered as "incompatible" as long as the `caption` package isn't adapted to it.

Now back to your questions:

Why the `revtex4-1` class is incompatible with the `subcaption` package? Because the `caption` package isn't adapted to the revtex4-1 document class yet.

Can this incompatibility be fixed easily? I don't know. For answering this I had to take a closer look at the sources of `revtex4-1`.

However, currently adapting the `caption` package to a document class means enhancing the `caption` package itself. This will change with the upcoming version 3.4 of the `caption` package which will offer a documented interface for these adaptions, so more people (or the author of the document class herself/himself) can offer these adaptions.

Comment: Great answer! BTW, IMHO, it is not lucky but your continuous maintenance that make the `caption` package realized. Thank you.

Comment: @Eli4ph I just took a first look at revtex4-1 and it seems the adaption to the caption package is not too difficult, maybe I'll try it on one of the next week-ends. But there is a challenge: revtex4-1 is patching the caption stuff from longtable, too, I have to take a closer look if and how I can manage that...