# How to setup the layout of caption justified?

Tags: captions, revtex

```
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering        
            \captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
            \begin{tikzpicture} 
            \matrix (fig)[matrix of nodes]{
            \includegraphics[width=2in]{example.pdf}    
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
        \end{figure}
```

I'm using a `revtex4-1` document class. I try to use `justification=justified` to justify the layout of the caption, but it still shows centering.

Comment: I believe the `caption` package is incompatible with the `revtex4-1` document class. Moreover, you're presumably using this document class because you've been asked to do so (e.g., to prepare your document for submission to a journal). It's almost certainly not a good idea to modify the formatting-related setting of such a specialized document class.

Comment: Thx, but without setup, the original caption is more absurd. I find the caption of a article generally is justified. How can I handle this?

Comment: To achieve your objective, you'll have to modify parts of the document class file. As I noted earlier, it's almost certainly a *very bad idea* to do so. Your personal preferences as to how figure captions should look like are almost certainly of no relevance to the journal's editors and other professional staff.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435118/why-the-revtex4-1-class-is-incompatible-with-the-subcaption-package