# Incompatibility issues within classicthesis

Tags: subfloats, incompatibility, subcaption, tocloft, classicthesis

I'm using `classicthesis.sty` to write my master's thesis. In this style the `tocloft` is set up with the `subfig` package, which is now deprecated, so i'm using instead the `subcaption` package, the problem is that they are incompatible and the `classicthesis.sty` has a lot of options with `subfig`.

I need some help to solve the compatibility issues. The table of contents is not getting compiled and neither are the references to bibliography or to figures in the document. I'm using Kile in Ubuntu and just beginning to learn Latex.

Here is some of my code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

% \input{classicthesis-config}
% In this input I have some of the following:
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,
             pdfspacing,
             subfig,
             beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{enable-backrefs} 
\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{false}

\newcounter{dummy}

\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
\usepackage{babel}                  
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc} 
\usepackage{inputenc} 

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
 \captionsetup{format=hang,font=small}
\usepackage{float} 
%\usepackage{subfig} 

\usepackage{classicthesis} 

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref} 
    \usepackage{hyperref}

\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 

\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 

\ifthenelse{\boolean{enable-backrefs}}%
{%
    \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperpageref}{backref}
    \usepackage{backref} 
       \renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} 
       \renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} 
       \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  
       \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
          \ifcase #1 %
             \backrefnotcitedstring%
          \or%
             \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2}%
          \else%
             \backrefcitedmultistring{#2}%
          \fi}%
}{\relax}    

\hypersetup{%
colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,%
breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,
urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, 
pdfsubject={},%
pdfkeywords={},%
pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
}   

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
    {%
   \addto\extrasspanish{%
                \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figura}%
                \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Cuadro}%
                \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Capítulo}%
                \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Sección}%
                \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Sección}%
                \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Sección}%     
          }%

            \providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}%             
}{\relax}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{spanish} 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% Table of Contents
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}        {\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents 
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}

% List of Figures and Tables
\clearpage

\begingroup 
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
% List of Figures
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures
\vspace*{8ex}

% List of Tables
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables
\vspace*{8ex}
\endgroup

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Dummy text} % 

\section{Lorem}

\lipsum[1-2] 
Foo bar baz (figure ~\ref{fig:ex1}).

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{graphs/dataset17b.pdf}
\end{center}
\caption{Example 1.}
\label{fig:ex1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not really clear how this question can be answered at the moment. Can you put together a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that actually shows what sort of incompatibility you need help resolving? Also, why not just use `subfig`? It's actually **not** deprecated. `subfigure` is the package that is deprecated. The only problem with `subfig` arises [if you need to use `hyperref`, too](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13631/32888).

Comment: @AdamLiter Thanks. I've uploaded an example that reproduces the problem (I'm sorry it's so long). And yes, I would like to use `hyperref` too.

Comment: @cfr Yes, `classicthesis` seems to be a pain. Could you recommend me something better?

Comment: @Tina Just use the KOMA class you've got and load the packages you need. That is, just drop `classicthesis` and tidy up your preamble so you can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,
             pdfspacing,
             subfig,
             beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
```

First, there is no reason to do this in the preamble for either this package or the others. Instead, just say

```
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,
             pdfspacing,
             subfig,
             beramono,eulermath,parts]{classicthesis}
```

Second, the option `subfig` is an option requesting `subfig`. So if you don't want `subfig`, don't tell the package to load it:

```
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,
             pdfspacing,
             beramono,eulermath,parts]{classicthesis}
```

Comment: Right, but this doesn't fix the table of contents nor the references within the text. The error message is: ./classicthesis.sty:428:Option clash for package tocloft.\newlength and There were undefined references.

Comment: @Tina Then you have another conflicting package or are passing `tocloft` incompatible options. Not loading `subfig` will avoid a conflict between `subfig` and `subcaption`. Obviously it will not fix further incompatibilities. For the references, you need to run any helper programmes (`bibtex` or `biber` and/or `makeglossaries` and/or whatever) and compile twice more. That warning is entirely normal. It just tells you further stuff needs doing.

Comment: @Tina You are loading `graphicx` twice, for example, and with a different set of options the second time. In general, your preamble is weird. Why all the conditional stuff? Why the `\PassOptions...` rather than `\usepackage[]...`. Sorting your preamble out will likely make it a lot easier to diagnose any remaining problems.

Comment: Yes, there was some incompatible option with `tocloft`, that fixed the table of contents. Now, the references issue is not a problem with `bibtex`, I meant the references to labeled figures within the same document. I'm not sure about the conditional stuff, they come in an separate input file that allows to configure the `classicthesis` and that you have to load on the main file, I put it in the preamble of the example above just to show how it was structured because there might be some errors with it.

Comment: @Tina You need to compile twice for the cross-references to resolve correctly.

Comment: I've tried that already and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Tina Then it is hard to help. 'It doesn't work' is not much to go on, really. Does the code you posted in the question demonstrate that problem? I haven't tried it as nobody but you can compile it without modification and I'm not clear whether it demonstrates the issue anyway.