# how to group images in a figure?

Tags: floats

I want to group images and assign the same sub-figure number in a figure consisting of several such groups. Please have a look at the following image to understand my question properly.

[image]

Comment: you can use subfigure https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig

Comment: @rpapa: I think that it will provide a number (i mean (a), (b), (c)...) to each sub-figure. But I need that a number is provided to a group of three figures only as depicted in my sample image above.

Comment: @skm use 3 `\includegraphics{...}` for each of the groups with `subfig` then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: May be, i did not understand your suggestion properly but i think that in that case, each group will become a separate figure which will not look good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two options, but the general idea is the same: to use one `subfigure` environment (requires `subcaption`) or `\subfloat` command (requires `subfig`) for each group.

Here's one option using the powerful [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}\par\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}\par\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Some grouped images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

And now with the help of the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
  \end{minipage}%
  }\par
  \subfloat[]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
  \end{minipage}%
  }\par
  \subfloat[]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}%
  \end{minipage}%
  }
  \caption{Some grouped images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Another option might be to use the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly fine. thank you so much.

Comment: @skm You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: Note alo the discussion [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure) about `subcaption` vs. `subfig`.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
\begin{figure}{h}
\subfigure[caption 1]{\label{...}
\includegraphics{img1-a}\hspace{1em}
\includegraphics{img1-b}\hspace{1em}
\includegraphics{img1-c}
}
subfigure[caption 2]{\label{...}
\includegraphics{img2-a}\hspace{1em}
\includegraphics{img2-b}\hspace{1em}
\includegraphics{img2-c}
}

\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This requires loading the `subfigure` package which is obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: Besides, using just  `h` as placement specifier is a recipe for disaster and the placement specifier goes as optional argument for `figure` and your code snippet uses it as mandatory argument.