# \listoffigures does not work with \subfig

Tags: table-of-contents

It seems \listoffigures does not work with \subfig. 
I do not receive an error, but compile is stoppped with the message `...amsfonts/umsb.fd`. 
How to fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}    
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[sample A]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{./figure/a.png}}
\subfloat[sample B]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{./figure/n.png}}\\
\caption{Sample.}
\label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: according to many resources (for instance http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure ) it is good practice tu use subcaptions instead of subfig. I personally changed to subcaption and the list of figures works for me.

Comment: Your example works fine for me and I don't see where amsfonts should enter. Are you really compiling the code you are showing? If yes show the log-file.

Answer (score 1):

Normally one doesn't include subcaptions in the list of figures.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}    
\begin{document}

\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}% include subcaptions
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[sample A]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfil
\subfloat[sample B]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}}% automatic \par from \caption
\caption{Sample.}
\label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

I know you already got an answer, but {subfig} isn't really the best way nowadays you know. Better to replace it with {subcaption}. To give an example what I always use:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}%

\RequirePackage{graphicx}%
\RequirePackage[hypcap=true]{caption}%
\RequirePackage[list=true,hypcap=true]{subcaption}% list=true ... print in List of Figures
\RequirePackage{hyperref}%

\captionsetup{hypcap=true}% -- hyperref
\captionsetup{rule=false}% reset make@caption to KOMA-Script,%
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=period,listformat=simple}%
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=period,listformat=simple}%
\captionsetup{format=plain}%
\makeatletter%
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{\thefigure.}%
\renewcommand\p@subtable{\thetable.}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}%
    \chapter{Sample}%
    \label{chap:Sample}%
    \section{Sample section}%
    \label{sec:Sample:Sample section}%
    \begin{figure}[h]%
        \captionsetup{justification=centering}% raggedright, justified, ...
        \subcaptionbox{sample A\label{subfig:Sample:sample A}}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
        \hfill%
        \subcaptionbox{sample B\label{subfig:Sample:sample B}}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
        \caption{Sample}%
        \label{fig:Sample}%
    \end{figure}%
    \listoffigures%
\end{document}
```

This gives something like (You can use it with the report-class if you don't want to replace it with scrreprt-class.):[image]