# 'Illegal parameter number in def' while loading subcaption package

Tags: subcaption

I'm trying to use the `subcaption` package with an old Elsevier template, but I get the following error

```
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

)
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty:71: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.71 ...achCaptionType{\DeclareCaptionSubType{#1}}
```

The code is very simple at this stage as it doesn't have any packages:

```
\documentclass[book,numbers]{elsbook-A07b}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

I have absolutely no idea what's causing the error as I've worked with the subcaption package for years without problem. I can't really include an MWE since that would include the whole template. I also know I shouldn't mess with the `subcaption.sty` file. I am wondering whether there's anything I can try to get rid of this error?

Comment: could you add more code? I cant guess how are you using the subcaption.

Comment: You shouldn't use `caption` with Elsevier classes: this is the meaning of the warning that's partially visible at the top. The people at Elsevier don't want that users fiddle with their preferred style. This said, you can use `subfig` for subfloats, loading it with `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`. Check its documentation for the syntax.

Comment: @egreg if I remove the `caption` package I get the same error, I guess perhaps because `subcaption` loads `caption` correct? What would you use instead of `subcaption`? I know it's supposed to be the best package for subfigures.

Comment: @aaragon `subcaption` is indeed based on `caption`, so loading only the former is the same as loading both. Neither should be used with that class. On the other hand, nobody can test for possible workarounds, because the class is not avaliable.

Comment: @SergioCavero I don't think I'm allowed to share the file `elsbook-A07b.cls`. Any my code is as small as I wrote at this point (just adding the package).

Comment: @egreg I've seen all over the internet the `subfig` package is not good. Apparently the package doesn't work with `hyperref` [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure). What is your take on that?

Comment: Ask the people at Elsevier.

Comment: Yeah, just did. I’ll post something here if useful for others.

Comment: You could try asking the maintainer of the `subcaption` package, too.